# Conceptual reason why the sign of a permutation is well-defined?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, permutations, intuition, gm.general-mathematics

Teaching group theory this semester, I found myself laboring through a proof that the sign of a permutation is a well-defined homomorphism $\operatorname{sgn} : \Sigma_n \to \Sigma_2$. An insightful student has pressed me for a more illuminating proof, and I'm realizing that this is a great question, and I don't know a satisfying answer. There are many ways of phrasing this question:

**Question:** Is there a conceptually illuminating reason explaining any of the following essentially equivalent statements?

1. The symmetric group $\Sigma_n$ has a subgroup $A_n$ of index 2.
2. The symmetric group $\Sigma_n$ is not simple.
3. There exists a nontrivial group homomorphism $\Sigma_n \to \Sigma_2$.
4. The identity permutation $(1) \in \Sigma_n$ is not the product of an odd number of transpositions.
5. The function $\operatorname{sgn} : \Sigma_n \to \Sigma_2$ which counts the number of transpositions "in" a permutation mod 2, is well-defined.
6. There is a nontrivial "determinant" homomorphism $\det : \operatorname{GL}_n(k) \to \operatorname{GL}_1(k)$.
7. ….

Of course, there are many proofs of these facts available, and the most pedagogically efficient will vary by background. In this question, I'm not primarily interested in the pedagogical merits of different proofs, but rather in finding an argument where the existence of the sign homomorphism looks *inevitable*, rather than a contingency which boils down to some sort of auxiliary computation.

The closest thing I've found to a survey article on this question is a 1972 note ["An Historical Note on the Parity of Permutations" by TL Bartlow](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.1972.11993124) in the American Mathematical Monthly. However, although Bartlow gives references to several different proofs of these facts, he doesn't comprehensively review and compare all the arguments himself.

Here are a few possible avenues:

- $\Sigma_n$ is a Coxeter group, and as such it has a presentation by generators (the adjacent transpositions) and relations where each relation respects the number of words mod 2. But just from the definition of $\Sigma_n$ as the group of automorphisms of a finite set, it's not obvious that it should admit such a presentation, so this is not fully satisfying.
- Using a decomposition into disjoint cycles, one can simply compute what happens when multiplying by a transposition. This is not bad, but here the sign still feels like an *ex machina* sort of formula.
- Defining the sign homomorphism in terms of the number of pairs whose order is swapped likewise boils down to a not-terrible computation to see that the sign function is a homomorphism. But it still feels like magic.
- Proofs involving polynomials again feel like magic to me.
- Some sort of topological proof might be illuminating to me.

Comment: So I guess your first and third bullet points have ruled out a proof of the form: "Draw the permutation by connecting dots on either sides of a strip. Use wiggly lines if you like, but only use normal crossings. Now count the number of crossings, and argue that this count mod 2 is a topological invariant."

Comment: Are you willing to take for granted that the orthogonal group has two components? Or the real general linear group? Because that's what you need in order to know something about determinants of matrices... but maybe that's *more* sophisticated than the sign representation of $S_n$, not less.

Comment: @markvs I don't actually know how to define the determinant (or else characterize it and prove its existence) without knowing that the sign of a permutation is well-defined.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd If there's a proof that $O(n)$ or $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ has two components which doesn't implicitly require one to know that the sign is well-defined (which as far as I can see, includes the case of relying on the existence of the determinant), that would be interesting.

Comment: @markvs Ok sure, but now we're back in the territory where it feels like magic that the determinant should be well-defined, because the proof boils down to checking that it's invariant under row operations. This feels particularly like magic to me because you have to put in "by hand" the prescription that row-swapping changes the sign of the determinant.

Comment: @TimCampion I agree --- I don't know a completely elementary calculation of $\pi_0 O(n)$. Certainly not if the benchmark for "elementary" is at or below "existence of a sign representation of $S_n$". Then again, I still think "draw some wiggly lines and count crossings" is rather elementary...

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd I guess my goal is not precisely to be elementary, but really to be conceptually illuminating, and it's hard for me to imagine the "invariance mod 2" part of the squiggly lines argument looking like more than a contingency. I wonder if there's a proof using unoriented bordism or something...

Comment: So when you ruled out things about polynomials, I guess you had in mind something like the following? Pick $n$ real numbers, all distinct, $x_1,\dots,x_n$, and write down $D := \prod_{i<j}(x_j-x_i)$. Now discover that a permutations act by $D \mapsto \pm D$.

Comment: For a topological construction, you can take the action of $S_n$ on $H_n(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^n-0) = \mathbb Z$.  For this, you  need to know that the top homology of a sphere is one dimensional.

Comment: Take the vertices of an $n$-simplex, and apply the permutation. If this turns the simplex inside out, then the permutation is odd; otherwise it is even. (This is basically equivalent to the comment by markvs, if one thinks of the determinant geometrically.)

Comment: This seems like a great [MESE](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com) question, but, surely, given its explicitly elementary nature, it is not an MO question?

Comment: If you think about the sign of a permutation as counting (the parity of) the number of inversions, rather than (the parity of) the number of transpositions, then I think #3 becomes much more clear. You still have to prove that this function is a homomorphism (see, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2071920/the-sign-function-is-a-homomorphism)), but at least you don't have to deal with any of the well-definedness issues.

Comment: @LSpice Although the motivation is partly pedagogical, at this point I'm not primarily interested in finding a proof which will optimally satisfy my students, but rather one which will satisfy me. Right now, I know that the sign of a permutation is a well-defined homomorphism, but I don't know "why, really".

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined#comment1071998_417690), of course different people will find a different 'real' answer as to why, but you seem to have explicitly ruled out many people's 'real' candidates for why.  If the goal is to satisfy you and not a student, then, for example, it's hard for me to imagine a much more convincing proof than @TheoJohnson-Freyd's [above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined#comment1071992_417690).

Comment: While I'm cluttering up the comments, I can't help noticing that (6) is false when $k = \mathbb F_2$ (and of course (1), (3), (5) are false for $n = 1$).

Comment: @NathanielJohnston Indeed, and that's actually how I'm teaching it this semester. What I'm actually hung up on is that the proof, using this definition, that you have a homomorphism, though not bad, is still delicate enough that it doesn't leave me feeling enlightened. Perhaps this is indeed too subjective.

Comment: @WillBrian True. Is there a way to see that "inside out" is well-defined without knowing already that the sign of the determinant is?

Comment: The proofs mentioned by Theo and by Phil are both of the form "exhibit an explicit nontrivial action of $\Sigma_n$ on a set with two elements". Ultimately, I suppose any proof will have to do this. Maybe one can't ultimately do better than this.

Comment: It seems to me that [tag:soft-question] is not suitable here (the tag is usually not meant in the case of a heuristic question, but rather of a question peripheral to mathematics). I'd rather see [tag:gm.general-mathematics] or [tag:intuition] instead.

Comment: The definition I learnt of determinant when studying was not based on row operations (invariance under row operations was proved afterwards), but essentially on the basis that the space of alternating $n$-forms on an $n$-dimensional space is 1-dimensional. So here the sign would be the action of a matrix in $\mathrm{Aut}(V)$, $V$ a free $\mathbf{Z}$-module of rank $n$, on $\Lambda_\mathbf{Z}^n(V)$.

Comment: @YCor Thanks, tags changed accordingly. That's a good point about the alternating power -- probably the "correct" definition of the determinant. I wonder if one can see that $\Sigma_k$ acts on $\Lambda^k V$ without knowing that the sign of a permutation is well-defined...

Comment: @TimCampion the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_k$ acts on $(\mathbf{Z}^k)^{\otimes n}$ in the obvious way. This action obviously preserves the subspace generated by all the tensors $v_1\otimes \dots v_n$ such that $v_i=v_j$ for some $i\neq j$. Hence it factors through an action on the quotient, which is $\Lambda^n(\mathbf{Z}^k)$. Now specify to $n=k$.

Comment: Usually the sign is used to show that the top exterior power is nonzero

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined#comment1072020_417690), for working over $\mathbb Z$ it suffices to show that the top exterior power over $\mathbb F_2$ is non-$0$, and that is exhibited by the fact that the mod-2 determinant, which requires no sign in its definition, factors through the top exterior power.  (Thinking along these lines is why I made my [silly comment about $\mathbb F_2$](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1072002).)

Comment: @LSpice but one still has to show the action of $S_n$ on the top exterior power is non-trivial.  That would seem to me to require some form of the sign map. You can't see that over F_2.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1072034), since the top exterior power is clearly spanned by the image $E$ of  $e_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes e_n$ (where $\{e_1, \dotsc, e_n\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb Z^n$), and since the top exterior power is non-$0$, we must have $E \ne 0$; but (now working over $\mathbb Z$) it is clear that any transposition takes $E$ to $-E$.  That is, we may show the top exterior power is non-$0$ by working over $\mathbb F_2$, but that the action of $\Sigma_n$ is non-trivial by working over $\mathbb Z$; no *a priori* signum character required.

Comment: @TimCampion: I suppose I was taking it as intuitively obvious. For evidence in my favor, I just asked my 4-year-old daughter, and she said that *she* knows what it means. I would count my previous comment as a conceptually clear explanation (to me, anyway), but I would not necessarily find it easy to turn the explanation into a rigorous proof.

Comment: @LSpice, How do you rigorously prove that $E\neq -E$ on the top exterior power of Z without using determinants or the sign?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined?noredirect=1#comment1072042_417690), if $E$ equalled $-E$, then $L \mathrel{:=} 2{\bigwedge}^n\mathbb Z^n$ would be trivial; but $L$ admits a sign-free, non-trivial determinant map to $2^n\mathbb Z/2^{n + 1}\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Theo’s first suggestion is essentially the proof that the first stable stem is Z/2Z.  Which is just to say maybe we should accept that this is a deep fact and so all proofs are saying something quite interesting.

Comment: @TimCampion I don't understand what troubles you about Will Brian's argument. What if we phrase it this way: Rotations give you $n!/2$ of the automorphisms of a simplex. This is clear by induction; rotate vertex 1 to any of $n$ vertices and then apply a rotation of one dimension lower. So this is a subgroup of index 2, which is your first equivalent formulation. Right?

Comment: @TimothyChow: Is the induction step you had in mind to first show that the group of rotations acts transitively on vertices and then say that rotations fixing your favorite vertex are rotations one dimension lower?

Comment: @NoahSnyder Almost. The second step is, rotations one dimension lower fix your favorite vertex. But I gather that Tim Campion is not asking for a proof that is "simpler" or that somehow avoids a step that other proofs take. He's asking for a way of looking at it that makes things seem "inevitable" or "not miraculous." I'd argue that this point of view makes $A_n$ seem like an obvious entity in its own right, rather than something that has to extricate itself from inside $S_n$. That it is a subgroup of index 2 then follows by noting that $n!/2$ is half of $n!$.

Comment: @TimothyChow: Don't you need both implications or else it could be that there are n! rotations.

Comment: @NoahSnyder No, I don't think so. I'm building up a group by multiplying by $n$ at each step. I don't need to prove that I'm getting "all" rotations, just that I'm getting a group of order $n!/2$.

Comment: @TimothyChow If you don’t know it’s all rotations how do you get closure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134650/discussion-between-timothy-chow-and-noah-snyder).

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/94348/19352

Comment: This question seems to have attracted a lot of attention … in some sense, too much, since the new answers are often duplicating answers that have already appeared in comments or other answers.  Is there some appropriate step to take when a question reaches that stage?  (Or perhaps we're not agreed that the question has reached that stage.)

Comment: Re: @LSpice's comment at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined#comment1072045_417690. How do you define the "sign-free, non-trivial determinant map to $2^n \mathbb{Z} / 2^{n + 1} \mathbb{Z}$"?

Comment: @LSpice [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/#comment1072319_417690) My inclination is to let it breathe for a little longer -- the question is still less than two days old. I think it's not a bad thing for answers from the comments to be "duplicated" as actual answers, and the level of duplication from one answer to another is acceptable so far at least to me (it helps that the eagle-eyed such as yourself have been pointing out in the comments when this occurs). Anyway, I will likely "accept" Bjorn Poonen's answer in a little while, maybe lending the question some air of "finality".

Comment: @SridharRamesh, you're right, I meant $2\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$.  [That](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined#comment1072356_417690) determinant map I was claiming only on $2{\bigwedge}^n\mathbb Z^n$, not on all of ${\bigwedge}^n\mathbb Z^n$.  It is defined by the usual formula, just with signs omitted.  (Since every term is divisible by $2$, the signs don't matter modulo $4$.)

Comment: I know how to define a linear map on all of $\wedge^n \mathbb{Z}^n$ using its universal property, but how are you proposing to define this map on only $2 \wedge^n \mathbb{Z}^n$? I'm worried about the non-uniqueness of representations of an element of $2 \wedge^n \mathbb{Z}^n$ by an $n$-tuple of elements of $\mathbb{Z}^n$. I would need to be assured that any two such representations yield the same matrix determinant or mod 4 permanent. The only way I know to assure this is defining via universal property a determinant on all of $\wedge^n \mathbb{Z}^n$, but for that the omitted signs DO matter.

Comment: That is, does $2\wedge^n \mathbb{Z}^n$ have some nice universal property in itself that makes this go through, that is automatically known without needing to establish $E \neq -E$ by some separate permutation parity argument? I'm not aware of that.

Comment: I'm wondering about a species-like description. Consider the category of finite sets and injections, and the subcategory of 2-element sets. Shouldn't the inclusion have a left adjoint where the counit is, more or less, the sign map? The functoriality and naturality may force some interesting behaviour. In particular, what is the 2-element set output by the left adjoint evaluated on some finite set?

Comment: Why do you feel a left adjoint exists? The counit would have to be an injection from an arbitrary finite set into a 2-element set. But most finite sets don't have injections into a 2-element set.

Another counterargument: A left adjoint would have to preserve initial objects, but the category of finite sets and injections has an initial object (the empty set has a unique injection into every set), while the category of 2-element sets and injections has no initial object (any 2-element set has two different injections to any other 2-element set).

Comment: @SridharRamesh because abelianisation is left adjoint to the inclusion, but you are right I completely butchered the functorial setup I was thinking of. What I really want is to have is the sign map as some natural transformation that incorporates not just bijections, so capturing the symmetric groups, but also injections between diff sets, hence capturing the inclusions between diff rank symmetric groups.

Comment: Ah, we all make mistakes. I just realized I said "counit" where I should have said "unit".

Comment: @SridharRamesh, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined/417693#comment1072372_417690), I see your point.  Would you buy it if I claimed that $2^n{\bigwedge}^n\mathbb Z^n$ equalled ${\bigwedge}^n(2\mathbb Z)^n$, showed that the latter was non-$0$ by mapping onto $2^n\mathbb Z/2^{n + 1}\mathbb Z$, and then concluded that $2{\bigwedge}^n\mathbb Z^n$ was non-$0$?  Or maybe showing that the obvious map $\leftarrrow$ in my claim is an isomorphism would involve a circularity.

Comment: I am writing mostly since your question caused me doubts in my own understanding and maybe this is also stupid (on top from a layman): I find it directly plausible that a permutation can by uniquely represented by its permutation matrix (once every element in X has been assigned to a integer from \{1,..,n\}). The sign is defined as the determinant of this matrix. Determinants don't change upon reordering the axis, and due to the nature of the matrix it's either 1 or -1. Where would be the magic bit in this approach in your eyes?

Comment: @RaphaelJ.F.Berger This reasoning is circular because the sign of a permutation appears in the usual formula for the determinant.

Comment: @TimCampion I had the recursive definition via the determinants of the minors in mind, actually. Then one needs of course to develop the properties of these determinants.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because enough conceptual reasons already.

Comment: One could define the determinant  via the Whitehead group. See Example 1.2. https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/milnorwh.pdf

Comment: Another silly way to define the determinant: compute the inverse of a square matrix with general variable entries, so that the entries of the inverse are rational functions of the matrix entries. Then there is a common denominator which is the determinant (up to scaling). Probably not very helpful, but maybe makes it seem inevitable.

Comment: I couldn't find if this is mentioned yet: you can define the sign of a permutation of $\{0,...n\}$ to be the degree of the map $S^n \to S^n$ it induces. (There are certainly ways to define the degree that already involve determinants, e.g. via oriented point counts; using algebro-topological definitions, this can be circumvented.)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

(This is a variant of Cartier's argument [mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/a/417727) by Dan Ramras.)

Let $X$ be a finite set of size at least $2$.  Let $E$ be the set of edges of the complete graph on $X$.  The set $D$ of ways of directing those edges is a torsor under $\{\pm1\}^E$.  Let $G$ be the kernel of the product homomorphism $\{\pm1\}^E \to \{\pm1\}$.  Since $(\{\pm1\}^E:G)=2$, the set $D/G$ of $G$-orbits in $D$ has size $2$.  The symmetric group $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ acts on $X$, $D$, and $D/G$, so we get a homomorphism $\operatorname{Sym}(X) \to \operatorname{Sym}(D/G) \simeq \{\pm 1\}$.  Each transposition $(ij)$ maps to $-1$ because if $d \in D$ has all edges at $i$ and $j$ outward except for the edge from $i$ to $j$, then $(ij)d$ equals $d$ except for the direction of the edge between $i$ and $j$.

Comment: This could be considered the "combinatorial core" of the polynomial argument mentioned by David Speyer.  It has the advantage of avoiding "external" ingredients like multivariable polynomials, topology, etc.  No computation is needed to  construct the homomorphism.  (Computation is needed only to check that it is nontrivial, but that is very easy, as explained in the last sentence above.)

Comment: Neat! Like my [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/417719/82179), this acknowledges the $S_2$-torsor $X^2 \setminus \Delta_X \to {X \choose 2}$ as the key object. But curiously, it doesn't quite generalise to the setting of my lemma, as the final $\{\pm 1\}$ somehow relies on the coincidence $\operatorname{Sym}(\{\pm 1\}) \cong \{\pm 1\}$. (This may well be a feature and not a bug.)

Comment: I think this one is "the" answer.

Comment: I agree with Sam -- this proof is from the Book! A few notes: 1.) To see that the action of $Sym(X)$ descends from $D$ to $D/G$, one should of course note that there is a compatibility of actions: $\sigma \cdot (d \cdot g) = (\sigma \cdot d) \cdot (\sigma \cdot g)$ for $\sigma \in Sym(X), d \in D, g \in G$ (my conventions: $Sym(X)$ acts on $X$ from the right, so acts on $D$ and $G$ from the left; $G$ acts on $D$ from the right). 2.) An instance of the last sentence, sufficient to see nontriviality of the action, is where $X = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$, $(i,j) = (1,2)$, and $d$ is the standard order.

Comment: My only complaint about this proof is that it's almost _too_ slick -- it suggests to me that by taking $G$ to be some _other_ $Sym(X)$-invariant subgroup of $\{\pm 1\}^E$, one could get all sorts of interesting homomorphisms out of $Sym(X)$. Of course, _a posteriori_ it must turn out that these are all just variations on $sgn$, but I would like to reflect on what is so special about this particular subgroup $G \subset \{\pm 1\}^E$.

Comment: I think it is special because it is the only index 2 invariant subgroup

Comment: The construction really just yields a nontrivial _action_ of $Sym(X)$ on a 2-element set. So if you choose a different subgroup $G'$, you'll get an action on a subgroup of a different size, and hence you'll get various subgroups of $Sym(X)$ from the istropy, but there's no reason for these isotropy subgroups to be normal. So in some sense we are using the fact that index 2 subgroups are alway normal. In fact, the argument implicitly includes a proof of this fact which is new to me.

Comment: Essentially this argument is in Algebre and Theories Galiosienne by Douady and Douady but they use a language of choice functions instead of orienting edges and argue more like Cartier.   This proof is slicker

Comment: I withdraw my reservation from my earlier comment: in a more general setting of $A^E \to A$ for an abelian group $A$, the analogous set $D/G$ does not have $2$ elements, but is still an $A^E/G$-torsor, so there is an injection $\iota \colon A^E/G \hookrightarrow \operatorname{Sym}(D/G)$. I believe that the commutators of the $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$- and $A^E$-actions on $D$ are in $G$, so that the image of $\operatorname{Sym}(X) \to \operatorname{Sym}(D/G)$ lands in the image of $\iota$. (Anyway, this is only relevant for generalisations, not for the question itself.)

Comment: I think there are only four Sym(X)-invariant subgroups of $\{\pm 1\}^E$ in general: The trivial maximal and minimal ones, the one called $G$ here, and the two-element one containing all +1 or all -1. Up to the action of Sym(X), all that matters about an element of $\{\pm 1\}$ is how many -1s it contains. And if such an element has a number of -1s strictly between 0 and |E|, then by multiplying it by a shifted over version of itself, so to speak, it generates an element with precisely two -1s, which in turn can be used to generate all elements with an even number of -1s (i.e., all of $G$).

Comment: @SridharRamesh I think I'd find that argument convincing if we were talking about $Sym(X)$-invariant subsets of $\{\pm 1 \}^X$, but the action of $Sym(X)$ on $\{\pm 1\}^E$ is "less transitive", and I think more needs to be said. The question is equivalently: if $V$ is a finite-dimensional $\mathbb F_2$-vector space, then how many $End(V)$-submodules does $\Lambda^2(V)$ have?

Comment: Oh, good point, I lost track of the difference between $X$ and $E$ here.

Comment: @SridharRamesh There is at least one more: The subgroup of sign patterns which multiply to $1$ around any cycle.

Comment: This has been an educational MO question for me, but I feel that I've learned more about mathematicians than about mathematics. Clearly, some other people's intuitions don't line up with my own, and I feel like I have to reverse engineer the mindset that makes certain arguments seem natural and others seem contrived.

Comment: It's interesting this proof relates to both the inversion-counting/polynomial proof and to the cycle-counting proof. The relation to inversion-counting is clear (consider directing edges linearly) and that this is the same as the polynomial proof is also straightforward (think of a directed edge as negating when reversed, and an element of D as the product of all its directed edges. The polynomial setup is where we specifically describe an edge as a difference of variables corresponding to its endpoints). But the relation to cycle-counting is perhaps less obvious.

Comment: I will write it out a bit tersely, because of character constraints. Hopefully it will still be understandable.

Instead of just considering the effect (as in, $\pm 1$) of $p \in Sym(X)$ on D/G = (orientations of all of E)/G, we can also consider p's effect on (orientations of E')/G for any subset $E' \subseteq E$ closed under the action of p. And the combined effect of p on a union of disjoint such E' is the product of its effects on the individual E'. In particular, we can break down E into its individual orbits under p, and consider the effect of p on each of these orbits separately.

Comment: Any cycle of X under p of even length 2n gives rise to an orbit of E under p of size n, this orbit comprising the diameters of the cycle. It is readily seen that these are all and only the orbits of E on which p's effect is -1. Thus, the overall effect of p on D/G is equal to (-1)^(the number of even length cycles of X under p).

Comment: @TimothyChow I also think people read the question differently. It specifically asks for a *conceptual* argument, so that's what I focused on. But it was inspired by an interaction with students, so quite a few answers focus on *elementary* or *slick* arguments instead (this is definitely missing from some of the answers, including mine). Poonen's answer combines the two. (Admittedly, this answer is what I *tried* to do, but I couldn't make it work as nicely.)

Comment: This is a fantastic answer! As a sort of "nitpik": there ought to be some easy and natural way to see how the parity of a cycle is related to the parity of the length of the cycle. What is it?

Comment: @TimothyChow: I'm curious. Are you saying that you don't share the widespread view that this argument is somehow more natural than many of the others?

Comment: @HJRW Yes, I don't find it more natural. Roughly speaking, it gives an *algebraic* proof of what I consider to be a *geometric* fact. Nothing wrong with that, but I don't find it any more *explanatory* than, say, simply counting inversions. That $A_n$ is the group of rotations of a simplex is, to me, the *explanation* for its existence.

Comment: @TimothyChow: In your explanation, how would you explain what "rotations of a simplex" are (especially for $n>4$), and how would you convince me that they do not generate the whole symmetric group?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais: WLOG $X=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $\sigma=(12\cdots k)$.  If $d \in D$ is given by the standard ordering, then $\sigma d$ is the same as $d$ except that the edges $\{i,k\}$ for $i=1,\ldots,k-1$ have been reversed.  Thus $\sigma$ maps to $(-1)^{k-1}$.

Comment: Re: HJRW: Personally, my view is that this argument is essentially the same as the standard polynomial argument given at https://mathoverflow.net/a/417692/3902, but abstracted a bit further out from the specific representation as polynomials. Or essentially the same as the standard inversion counting argument, but relaxed from specifically demanding a linear order. In that sense, it is essentially the same as very many of the answers given, or approaches already noted in the question. But abstracted out nicely to a point where it feels more natural or less ad hoc, at least to many.

Comment: @BjornPoonen I've mentioned this in other comments. Following Atiyah, I will accept the devil's offer to use algebra if you insist on a formal answer to your question. But in my soul I know that the true explanation for $A_n$ is geometric. Algebra is just there to silence the skeptics. (Again, I'm focusing on *conceptual explanation* rather than *formal proof*.)

Comment: Even in 3 dimensions, capturing our geometric intuition of a rotation is formally difficult. The conventional approach requires us to construct the real numbers and describe continuous transformations that preserve the metric. But to me this does not imply that rotations in 3 dimensions are a complicated concept. It says more about the gap between our intuitive grasp of geometry and our ability to formalize it.

Comment: @TimothyChow: If I understand you correctly, you are arguing that certain geometric notions like the notion of orientation of Euclidean space are more fundamental than the algebra currently used to formalize them.  Maybe you are even speculating that someday there will be a more geometric approach to foundations in which the existence of sgn is immediate?  I do like this line of thought, though I don't know if it will be possible.

Comment: @BjornPoonen Such a geometric approach to foundations would be very exciting, though I doubt that it will be realized any time soon. For a small but very interesting step in this direction, I recommend [Euclid and His Twentieth Century Rivals](https://www.unco.edu/nhs/mathematical-sciences/faculty/miller/pdf/euclid20thcenturyrivalsmiller.pdf) by Nathaniel Miller and related work such as [A formal system for Euclid's *Elements*](https://doi.org/10.1017/S1755020309990098).

Comment: @TimothyChow: Thanks, that's interesting. It seems that there's something more to do: to convince oneself that $A_n$ (perhaps characterised as in this answer) is the exactly $S_n\cap SO(n)$. From this point of view, it's essential to extend this kind of reasoning about the sign map to the determinant.

Comment: I had to look up what a torsor is, but I can see now that this is a particularly elegant proof. So I hate to complain, but in what sense is it a conceptual proof?

Comment: For the sake of others: To say that $D$ is a torsor under $\{\pm1\}^E$ just means that $\{\pm 1\}^E$ acts simply transitively on $D$.  The construction of $Sym(X) \to Sym(D/G)$ is conceptual in the sense asked for, that no auxiliary computation is required to verify that it is well-defined or that it is a homomorphism.  To me, it is obvious that the construction $X \mapsto D/G$ defines a functor from the category (finite sets of size $\ge 2$, bijections) to the category (size $2$ sets, bijections), and then it is automatic that one gets $Sym(X) \to Sym(D/G)$.

Comment: That this is a functor is saying that if you relabel the elements of $X$ using a bijection $X \to Y$, then you get a corresponding relabeling $D_X/G_X \to D_Y/G_Y$ (and that this respects composition, ...)  This is clear conceptually since the construction never uses the names of the elements of $X$.

Comment: @BjornPoonen, thanks for elaborating. You've sold me on this.

Comment: @Bjorn I was hoping for an explanation like this, but with the functor extended to finite sets and _injections_ (of size >1)

Comment: @DavidRoberts: What you want does not exist.  Any functor from (finite sets of size $\ge 2$, injections) to (size 2 sets, bijections) maps every automorphism to an identity morphism.  For an example of what goes wrong, ask what the functor would do to the composition $\{1,2\} \to \{1,2,3,4\} \to \{1,2,3,4\}$ consisting of the inclusion followed by the transposition $(34)$.  More generally, the problem is that every permutation is the restriction of an even permutation on some larger set.

Comment: @BjornPoonen yes, thanks for disabusing me of the notion. But I'm glad that something that is in the neighbourhood of combinatorial species did make an appearance, in the end!

Comment: @TimothyChow I tend to think of this proof as a _combinatorial_ proof rather than an _algebraic_ one. In fact, this is one reason I prefer it to the polynomial proof, because I think of $\Sigma_n$ as an object which is "fundamentally combinatorial in nature". Besides aesthetic value, it makes the proof more "portable" -- if I have some other setting where I want to set up a theory analogous to the theory of symmetric groups, it's nice to have a minimum of conceptual apparatus which needs to be replicated in the new setting in order to reproduce basic facts like the existence of $sgn$.

Comment: @TimCampion I guess it depends on your vantage point. From where I sit, the "combinatorial proof" would be simply noting the parity of the number of inversions in the one-line representation of a permutation, and the behavior of this invariant under transpositions. As soon as we start talking about actions or homomorphisms or even groups, it becomes algebraic to me.

Comment: @TimothyChow I see your point; let me push back a bit. In general, mathematical arguments resist this sort of classification into subfields. And this is already the case here: True, a group may be defined as a set with an operation satisfying axioms -- an algebraic definition. But a group may also be defined as a category with one object and every morphism invertible -- a category-theoretic definition; a group action is a presheaf. Or, a group may be defined as a connected, 1-truncted homotopy type -- a homotopy-theoretic definition; a group action is a fibration with discrete fibers.

Comment: Personally, I'm so accustomed to groups arising in my life via one of the latter two constructions that I barely think of them as algebraic objects at all! On the flip side, a great deal of combinatorics can be discussed in the language of combinatorial species, and thus in terms of actions of symmetric groups; to me the appearance of a combinatorial species doesn't mean we've switched from doing combinatorics to algebra.

Comment: @TimCampion: Are not the Vandermonde determinant and the associated moment polynomials, symmetric function/polynomial theory, volumes and combinatorics of the n-simplices / hypertriangles / hypertetrahedrons, wedge products, the complete graphs, the symmetric groups, and Coxeter reflection groups inextricably intertwined and so must combinatorics, algebra, and geometry in these 'answers' be ultimately interrelated? (The usual biases and skewed familiarity researchers have for and with these topics then influence the voting for 'THE' answer.)

Answer (score 76):

This is obviously a subjective question, but I teach this in two phases

(1) I need to know this fact very early, so I give the quickest definition I know:
$$\mathtt{sign}(\sigma) = \frac{\prod_{i<j} \left( x_{\sigma(i)} - x_{\sigma(j)} \right)}{\prod_{i<j} \left( x_i - x_j \right)}.$$
This makes it clear that $\texttt{sign}$ is well defined and is a group homomorphism, but does look rather like pulling a rabbit out of a hat. On the positive side, it is early practice in computing group actions on polynomials, which the students need any way.

But then, for motivation, a week or two later:

(2) I have students classify all group homomorphisms $\chi: S_n \to A$ where $A$ is abelian. Since $S_n$ is generated by transpositions, $\chi$ is determined by its value on transpositions. Since any two transpositions are conjugate, there must be one value $z$ which is $\chi((ij))$ for all $i$, $j$, since $(ij)^2=1$, we must have $z^2=1$. So either we have the trivial character, or else we can call $z$ by the name $-1$ and we have the sign character.

This explains why $\mathtt{sign}$ is inevitable — it is the only nontrivial character of $S_n$, so anyone mucking around with $S_n$ has to discover it.

As a bonus, the computation in part (2) can exactly be mimicked to show that $A_n$ has no nontrivial characters for $n \geq 5$: $A_n$ is generated by $3$-cycles, any character must take the $3$-cycles to cube roots of unity, but (for $n \geq 5$) every $3$-cycle is conjugate to its inverse, so in fact every character is trivial on the $3$-cycles.

Comment: I like this answer, although it seems to be ruled out by the question. It is clear that the differences between numbers change at most by a sign if we write them down in a different order.

Comment: Historically, I think (1) isn't just a rabbit from a hat—it connects up quite well with the idea of factoring the group determinant, which was the motivation for the original notion of a (possibly non-linear) group character.

Comment: Agree with this second approach. The point is that the sign is the only miracle that can occur, that it actually does occur is still a bit of a miracle.

Comment: I wonder if any basic result from the character theory of finite groups tells you there has to be another linear character beyond the trivial representation. I'm not seeing anything (don't see e.g. how you can use sum of dimensions squared equals $n!$) but who knows...

Comment: $\prod_{i < j} (x_{\sigma(i)} - x_{\sigma(j)}) = (-1)^{d} \prod_{i < j} (x_{i} - x_{j})$, where $d$ is the number of inversions of $\sigma$. So I always think of (1) as a clever trick for showing that the number of inversions mod $2$ defines a homomorphism $S_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Why not just $\prod_{i<j}(\sigma(i)-\sigma(j))/\prod_{i<j}(i-j)$?  There is no need to introduce polynomials.

Comment: I agree with Noah. The existence of the sign mapping is a nonobvious aspect of permutations. In retrospect, that $S_n$ has just one nontrivial proper normal subgroup for $n \geq 5$ (or just $n \not= 4$) explains why there is a sign mapping, but I don't think the sign is something we should expect a priori to exist for an intuitive reason. For comparison, the number of transpositions that multiply to a permutation in $S_n$ has no special properties mod $m$ for $m > 2$, and the number of 3-cycles that multiply to a permutation in $A_n$ has no special property mod $m$ for $m \geq 2$.

Comment: It seems to me somewhat common in algebra that uniqueness can be proved in a clean way but existence requires getting one's hands dirty. The Lie group E8, the Monster group -- there was a gap between when the properties of the conjectural object were described (root system, character table) and when the object was proved to exist. Why shouldn't it be similar for homorphisms $S_n \to \mathbb{C}^{\ast}$?

Comment: @NeilStrickland Using $\prod_{i<j} (x_{\sigma(i)}-x_{\sigma(j)})$ and $\prod_{i<j} (x_i-x_j)$ does not require introducing polynomials, we can just work with functions $\mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ (the set of which is acted on by the symmetric group).

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault, as functions [these](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined#comment1072323_417692) vanish in some places, and you can't divide them—or, at least, dividing them involves at least conceptually viewing them as polynomials.  I guess you could instead view them as functions on the complement of the diagonal, but that seems like a lot of work just to avoid polynomials (and I'm not sure most students understand abstract functions better than polynomials anyway!).

Comment: @LSpice I don't think dividing them is needed: one just compares the two functions, which must differ by a sign factor. Then one argues that these functions are not identically zero, so no need to remove the diagonal or know about polynomials as far as I can see. Of course there is always the debate of whether we should take the shortest path, but I always found choosing $x_i=i$ a bit unnatural. It is less conceptual in that it does not obviously generalize to an arbitrary symmetric group.

Comment: @NeilStrickland: With polynomials, it is easy prove that the map is a homomorphism, since $S_n$ acts on $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$. Using your suggestion, you need to show that the number of inversions mod $2$ defines a homomorphism $S_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Which is not that difficult but maybe not as slick.

Comment: @spin With the "quick" definition, it is not too complicated to prove directly that the sign is a homomorphism, it just requires some manipulation of the product. But I find this computation less transparent; the approach with polynomials/functions shows explicitly there is a group action behind the definition of the sign.

Comment: Another approach to motivation, not quite as easy, might be to ask: what is the subgroup $H\le S_n$ generated by all $3$-cycles? Easy enough computations show that $S_n=H\cup Ht$ for some transposition $t$.

Comment: @RichardLyons: Without sign, how to show that a transposition is not a product of $3$-cycles?

Comment: @spin: One has to show that a transposition times a product of 3-cycles has cycle decomposition with an odd number of even cycles. Not so clean. But I meant this just as a possible substitute for David Speyer's "motivation."

Comment: @NoahSnyder: I think this easy proof for uniqueness pairs well with the Galois proof I gave at the end, giving an "easy" existence proof with no verifications needed.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault, David - I've thought about this a bit (perhaps not enough!) and I still do not see the "manipulation of the product" your comment/answer suggests. Any hints?

Comment: @SamNead $\prod_{i<j} (\sigma(i)-\sigma(j))/(i-j) = \prod_{i<j} (\sigma(\tau(i))-\sigma(\tau(j)))/(\tau(i)-\tau(j))$ using the bijection between pairs $\{i,j\} \mapsto \{\tau(i),\tau(j)\}$ (the factor in the product is invariant under exchanging $\tau(i)$ and $\tau(j)$).

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault - Ah, quite right.  Thank you.

Answer (score 51):

Draw a braid on $n$ strings sloppily, so that no three strings pass through the same point.  Convince yourself  that the parity of the number of crossings is the same in every other drawing of the same braid. (By looking  at two of the strings.) Notice that composition of braids gives addition of the number of crossings.

Comment: This is my favorite way, as this count is essentially a geometric representation of the first cohomology of symmetric groups with Z/2 coefficients.  The entire cohomology can be understood in similar terms!

Answer (score 26):

This is an elaboration of [Will Brian's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined/417692#comment1071995_417690).  As I understand it, the goal isn't to find the simplest possible proof or a proof that is most palatable to students; the goal is to make things seem "inevitable" or "not miraculous." To achieve this goal, I think it is best to **view $A_n$ as an entity in its own right**, rather than start with $S_n$ and then try to extricate $A_n$ from $S_n$.  Rotations of a simplex provide a natural realization of $A_n$.  We can build a group of order $n!/2$ inductively, by starting with $n=3$ (rotations of a triangle) and multiplying by $n$ at each step.

Once you've constructed $A_n$, then you can construct $S_n$ as the group of "signed rotations," which has twice as many elements.  The "miracle" now is that there exists such an extension of $A_n$, but that presumably seems less miraculous.

Comment: Is it clear that you can define what it means for a permutation of the vertices of a simplex to be orientation-preserving (in other words, what a "rotation" of the simplex is) without an appeal to the notion of sign of a permutation (or something similar like a determinant)?

Comment: @SamHopkins I'm not claiming that one can construct a formal proof without ever introducing the concept of the sign of a permutation. What I'm suggesting is that one's geometric intuition suggests that there is a group of order $n!/2$ since this is obvious for $n=3$ and $n=4$, and one does not expect this pattern to suddenly break down for some larger value of $n$. It isn't a miracle that the obvious conjecture is true; it would be a miracle if it weren't. That converting geometric intuition into formal proofs might require some machinery doesn't mean that there's a deep fact involved.

Comment: If our minds worked slightly differently, then the inductive nature of passing from rotations in $n$-space to $(n+1)$-space might seem more obvious than the inductive nature of syntactic objects. That we feel the need to represent a rotation of a simplex using (say) a linear ordering of labels attached to the vertices says more about what we feel a rigorous proof is than what things are inevitably true. By contrast, the sporadic simple groups seem like genuine miracles.

Comment: "What I'm suggesting is that one's geometric intuition suggests that there is a group of order $n!/2$ since this is obvious for $n=3$ and $n=4$, and one does not expect this pattern to suddenly break down for some larger value of $n$."  I was trying to think of how I would respond to the obvious question of "Why not, since there are many examples of patterns in geometry that break in high enough dimensions?"  I suppose it boils down to the fact that $n$-simplices are primitive enough(?).

Comment: @TimothyChow: I’m with PaceNielsen here. There are *many* examples in geometry of sporadic, low-complexity examples that don’t extend to higher dimensions.

Comment: @PaceNielsen Of course one can always be a skeptic; $e+\pi$ could be rational for all we know. There are many rational numbers after all! I am only saying that my intuition is that $e+\pi$ is irrational. It would be a miracle if it weren't. Similarly, it's a miracle that $\mathbb{R}^4$ has uncountably many differentiable structures.

Comment: @TimothyChow The beauty of modern mathematics is that it gives us tools to develop and refine **better** intuition about problems, and to question old intuitions.  Miracles can, and do, happen in mathematics all the time.  Thus, if someone gives multiple examples of patterns that stop in higher dimensions, that's when we need to question, refine, and re-explain our intuition.  Now, for the big surprise: I wasn't being skeptical in the slightest!  I really do think that some intuitions are valid because there is no complicating factor to create miralces.  For example, my geometric intuition...

Comment: about the (recursive) existence of $n$-dimensional space comes from the idea that there is nothing to prevent the addition of another direction, based on my experience of passing from 1-D to 2-D to 3-D, and the basic character of this construction.  My brain may not have the ability to (easily) picture 4-dimensions or more, but I have no doubt that they are equiconsistent with lower dimensional space.  (This intuition is, *a fortiori*, strengthened using $n$-tuples of numbers, which may be, as you say, a function of how human minds work.)  Similarly,...

Comment: I was arguing **for** your position (which seemed to be misunderstood by HJRW and yourself).  The truly primitive nature of the $n$-simplex concept prevents complication/miracles.  To sum up: I don't question the value of intuition, but it isn't immune to questions.  (By the way, this same "primitivity" concept doesn't necessarily apply to $e+\pi$.  I have no intuition on its specific rationality status---though an educated guess would be that it is irrational, as you mentioned.)

Comment: One can "geometrise" this argument a little further by seeing that $S_n$ is the group of rigid motions of a "bi-pyramid" (of dimension $n+1$) over the $n$-simplex. It is clear that this contains $A_n$ which is the group of rigid motions of the $n$-simplex. Unlike my other answer below, this uses *only* rotations and avoids reflections. (I hope it is clear what I mean by a "bi-pyramid".)

Answer (score 25):

Some years ago, Keith Dennis posted a nice discussion of signs of permutations on the Group-Pub-Forum mailing list, following some papers by Cartier. I gave it to my graduate algebra class as a series of exercises, which I'll copy below. Dennis also pointed out that Cartier used similar ideas to give alternate viewpoints on the group-theoretic transfer and on Legendre symbols. References to Cartier's papers follow.

The complete graph $K_n$ on $\{1, 2, 3, \dotsc, n\}$ is the graph with $n$ vertices and with an edge connecting every pair of distinct vertices.  An orientation of $K_n$ is a choice of direction for each edge (formally, the edges are sets consisting of two distinct vertices, and an orientation just selects an ordering for each such set).
Note that we don't require any kind of compatibility between the orderings of different edges.

If $o$ and $o'$ are orientations of $K_n$, we define $m(o, o')$ to be the number of edges on which the orientations differ, and we set $d(o,o') = (-1)^{m(o,o')}$.

Prove the following statements:

a) $d(o,o')d(o',o'') = d(o,o'')$ for all orientations $o, o', o''$ of $K_n$;

b) The symmetric group $S_n$ acts on the set of orientations of $K_n$.  Formally, if $o$ is an orientation in which the edge between $i$ and $j$ points from $i$ to $j$, then in the orientation $\sigma \cdot o$, the edge between $\sigma(i)$ and $\sigma(j)$ points from  $\sigma(i)$ to $\sigma(j)$.  Prove that this defines an action, and show that $d(o, \sigma\cdot o) = d(o', \sigma \cdot o')$  for all orientations $o, o'$ of $K_n$ and all $\sigma \in S_n$.

We can now define $\operatorname{sgn} (\sigma) = d(o, \sigma o)$.

c) Prove that $\operatorname{sgn}: S_n \rightarrow \{\pm1\}$ is a homomorphism.

d) Prove that $\operatorname{sgn} (\tau) = -1$ for every transposition $\tau$.

References:

1. Zbl 0195.03101 Cartier, P. [Remarques sur la signature d'une
   permutation](https://dx.doi.org/10.5169/seals-43848) (French) Enseign. Math., II. Sér. 16, 7-19 (1970).
2. Zbl 0195.04001 Cartier, P. [Sur une généralisation du transfert en
   théorie des groupes](https://dx.doi.org/10.5169/seals-43851) (French) Enseign. Math., II. Sér. 16, 49-57
   (1970).
3. Zbl 0195.05802 Cartier, P.  [Sur une généralisation des symboles de
   Legendre–Jacobi](https://dx.doi.org/10.5169/seals-43850) (French) Enseign. Math., II. Sér. 16, 31-48 (1970).

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I changed the target of $\operatorname{sgn}$ from $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ to $\{\pm1\}$.  To get a $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$-valued map, I think you'd want just to define $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) = m(o, \sigma\cdot o)$.

Comment: Also, I like this approach, but isn't it the argument by counting inversions, as [suggested](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined#comment1071997_417690) by @NathanielJohnston?

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for the correction (I just updated my old problem set too...). I don't see how to match this up with inversions. The number of inversions in a permutation is a fixed number, but the number $m(o, \sigma o)$ depends on $o$ (of course the point is that changing $m(o, \sigma o)$ is equivalent to $m(o', \sigma o')$ (mod 2) for any two orientations $o$ and $o'$). But maybe you have something in mind to connect orientations and inversions that I'm not thinking of at the moment.

Comment: This is pretty much equivalent to the approach using $\prod\limits_{1\leq i<j\leq n} \dfrac{\sigma\left(i\right)-\sigma\left(j\right)}{i-j}$, particularly if this product is rewritten in the more symmetric form $\prod\limits_{\left\{i,j\right\}\in \mathcal{P}_2\left(\left[n\right]\right)} \dfrac{\sigma\left(i\right)-\sigma\left(j\right)}{i-j}$. But it's a nice way to avoid fractions!

Comment: Thanks, this proof is very nice! It's related to the proof I used in my class. The proof I used differs in that there one picks a favorite orientation $o_{std}$ (in practice, one does this using the linear ordering on $\{1,\dots,n\}$), and defines $sgn(\sigma) = m(o_{std}, \sigma \cdot o_{std})$, then verifies directly that $sgn(\sigma \cdot \tau) = sgn(\sigma) \cdot sgn(\tau)$. This amounts to the same work as your (a) + (b), but by separating them out like this, the proof you're describing looks much more natural!

Comment: @TimCampion I had previously done this by discussing inversions, and decided I liked this better. I was probably somewhat swayed by Dennis's enthusiasm about it in his email. I should admit that the students were mostly rather confused about how the symmetric group acts on orientations, so presenting it via exercises didn't work as well as I'd hoped. But that depends a lot on the students - I think it's largely about how comfortable they are with notation.

Comment: Douady and Douady give this argument in Algebre and Theories Galiosienne but instead of talking about orientations they talk about choice functions which select one element from each ordered pair.   The action then becomes on functions and so which might be easier

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg That makes sense. I like drawing the graph pictures, but notationally I bet the choice functions would be simpler for students to work with as an exercise.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1072131), the relation I had in mind to the number of inversions is that, if $K_n$ is given its "usual" orientation $o$ (where $\{i, j\}$ is oriented from $i$ to $j$ whenever $I < j$), then $m(o, \sigma\cdot o)$ is the number of inversions (isn't it?  Or else I have misunderstood the definition).  As you say, one can obtain counts that agree with the number of inversions only up to parity by choosing different orientations; but one choice leads naturally to that count.

Comment: ([Further](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined/417727#comment1072272_417727), @darijgrinberg made, or at least I understand them to have made, the [point](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined/417727#comment1072190_417727) that I was trying to make, but, of course, more eloquently.)

Comment: @LSpice Ok, I see. Maybe this is like a "coordinate-free" version of the inversion argument. I'll note that part a) is useful in the later steps, i.e. it's helpful, at least conceptually and notationally, to consider orientations other than the standard one.

Comment: Conceptually, this approach seems to bring me to the following two basic identities concerning the symmetric difference: $(A\Delta B)\Delta(B \Delta C) = A\Delta C$ and $|A\Delta B|=|A|+|B|-2|A\cap B|$. Unfortunately, the first one may not be that intuitive or conceptual.

Answer (score 24):

A fun answer: You would not be able to ask this question otherwise : No fermions and no stable matter in our Universe.

Comment: Proof by the anthropic principle :D

Comment: Well, this is a proof that there is a homomorphism $S_n \to \{ \pm 1 \}$ for $n$ less than the number of particles in the universe :).

Answer (score 20):

This argument is not drastically different from some of the other answers, but I'm going to write it down for the record. It is a kind of unbiased version of the inversion counting argument and can also be seen as a simplification of the argument via the action on the set of orientations of the complete graph.

Let $X$ be a finite set with at least $2$ elements and let $T_X$ be the set of total orders on $X$. Consider the following relation $\sim$ on $T_X$: two orders are equivalent if the number of $2$-element subsets of $X$ on which they disagree is even. Check that this is an equivalence relation with exactly two equivalence classes. The symmetric group $\Sigma_X$ acts on $T_X$ and respects $\sim$. Thus $\Sigma_X$ acts on the $2$-element set $T_X / {\sim}$ and any transposition acts non-trivially. It follows that $\Sigma_X \to \Sigma_{T_X / \sim}$ is a surjective homomorphism.

Comment: This could be viewed as a variant of @DanRamras's Cartier-inspired [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/417727) using orientations on $K_n$, where we use only 'compatible' orientations (those respecting a total order).

Comment: Yes, I have noted that. I even dared to say that it is a simplification of that argument since I find it easier to think about the set of total orders as opposed to the set of all orientations.

Comment: I like this answer as it builds a bridge between two other answers I read earlier, clarifying them both: the accepted answer linked to in the first comment on this answer and Wilberd van der Kallen's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/417941/41139) using braids.

Comment: I think that from a pedagogical standpoint, this is my favorite answer. Every time I think about the action of the symmetric group on orientations, I feel slightly worried I'm getting it wrong, and when I gave the exercises in my answer to students, they got stuck on exactly this point. On the other hand, I find the action of the symmetric group on total orders very simple to think about; it "feels" just like the action on {1, ..., n}. So I definitely agree with @KarolSzumiło that this is a welcome simplification.

Comment: Maybe it is worth also noting that the missing step ("Check...") is easier than I expected it to be, basically because given total orders $T, S, R$, there's a simple counting argument for comparing the number of differences $T\to S$, $S\to R$, and $T\to R$, and one doesn't need to consider the permutations in this step at all.

Comment: @DanRamras That's my thinking exactly. When I was trying to understand the action on the set of orientations, I wrote it down wrong at first. Working out my mistake is what led me to notice that it seems simpler when we restrict attention to total orders.

Comment: You shouldn't write $T_X/\sim,$ but rather $T_X/{\sim}$ (coded as `T_X/{\sim}`) since the former put the same space to the left of $ \text{“}{\sim}\text{”}$ as in $a\sim b,$ where it is used as a binary relation symbol.

Answer (score 17):

Fun question!

I encountered a similar pedagogical problem when I wrote the article
["The Grassmann–Berezin calculus and theorems of the matrix-tree type"](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aam.2003.07.002)
about Grassmann/Fermionic variables. This could be item 7 in the OP's list.

Let $\xi_1,\dotsc,\xi_n$ be formal variables or symbols.
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit which contains $\mathbb{Q}$.
Consider $R\langle\xi_1,\dotsc,x_n\rangle$ the free noncommutative $R$-algebra generated by the symbols $\xi$, namely formal $R$-linear combinations of words in the symbols $\xi$ with concatenation as a product. Let $I$ be the two sided ideal generated by the elements
$\xi_i\xi_j+\xi_j\xi_i$ for all $i$, $j$ (not necessarily distinct).
Finally consider the quotient algebra $R[\xi_1,\dotsc,\xi_n]=R\langle\xi_1,\dotsc,x_n\rangle/I$.
It is trivial to see that the $2^n$ monomials $\xi_{i_1}\dotsm\xi_{i_k}$, with $0\le k\le n$ and $1\le i_1<\dotsb<i_k\le n$, $R$-linearly generate $R[\xi_1,\dotsc,\xi_n]$. However, one needs a little bit of work to show linear independence. Once this is done, then one can define the sign of a permutation $\sigma$
as *the* coefficient of
$\xi_{\sigma(1)}\dotsm\xi_{\sigma(n)}$
with respect to the basis element $\xi_1\dotsm\xi_n$.

I had a fun proof of this linear independence while pretending not knowing anything about determinants, exterior algebra, etc. I don't remember it perfectly but the key fact was that if one makes a graph with vertices corresponding to all words in the $\xi$'s of a fixed length and putting an edge when two words differ by switching two consecutive $\xi$'s, then this graph is *bipartite*.

**Variant:** (with topology?)

When teaching linear algebra, I often define the sign of a permutation as follows. Represent the permutation $\sigma$ as a bunch of left to right arrows between two columns representing two copies of the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, then let $c(\sigma)$ be number of crossings between arrows. Now if $\tau$ is another permutation, draw the analogous diagram for $\tau$ immediately to the right of sigma, as a continuation. Then I explain that $c(\tau\circ\sigma)-c(\tau)-c(\sigma)$ is even. Suppose arrows are made of rubber strings and that they are pinned in the middle where the two permutations are connected. Upon release the elastic strings straighten, but when doing so crossings always disappear in pairs.
Of course once this is clear, one immediately has a homomorphism $\sigma\mapsto (-1)^{c(\sigma)}$.

Comment: I changed your link direct to ScienceDirect to a DOI link.  I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Is it for more robust referencing? Thanks for fixing the xi typo also.

Comment: [Exactly](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined#comment1072015_417694) (and my pleasure)!  Elsevier behaves better than Springer in terms of not engaging in constant re-arrangements, but I still prefer the extra layer of protection.

Comment: By the way, @TheoJohnson-Freyd also [mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined#comment1071982_417690) the (pseudo-)topological proof you reference.

Comment: @LSpice: you're right, I didn't see Theo's comment.

Comment: You can prove linear independence in the exterior algebra using the diamond lemma for rings, but I'm not sure whether this can be regarded as "conceptual".

Comment: @darijgrinberg: thanks for letting me know about this body of literature. I suppose you are referring to things like https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870878900105

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant (see also https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5366 for more advanced strategies).

Answer (score 14):

There are already plenty of other great answers, but I figured I might as well give my own.

My approach is to introduce students to permutations by taking plastic cups that have large numbers on them, say consecutively numbered from $1$ to $8$, and then move them around (like in a "3 cup Monte" exhibition) in a random fashion, and end up with a permutation of them.  For concreteness, let's say that the cups end up in the order
$$
\begin{matrix}3 & 5 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 7 & 6 &8\end{matrix}.
$$
We will focus on this permutation for the rest of the explanation.

Now, it is easy to show students that this permutation can easily be obtained by transpositions.  But it is in fact easy to show them that this permutation is obtained by transpositions where the entries of the transposition are consecutive numbers $(i\ i+1)$, which we will call **swaps**.

For instance, starting with
$$
\begin{matrix}1 & 2& 3 & 4& 5& 6& 7 &8\end{matrix}
$$
we can first push cup $3$ past cup $2$, and then past cup $1$ to get
$$
\begin{matrix}3 & 1& 2& 4& 5& 6& 7 &8\end{matrix},
$$
so cup $3$ is in the correct position.  Next, we push cup $5$ past $4$, then $2$, then $1$, to get
$$
\begin{matrix}3 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 7 &8\end{matrix},
$$
so now both cup $3$ and cup $5$ are in the correct positions.  Continuing in this way, we can get all the cups in the correct positions using just swaps.  We might call this the "left-swap" algorithm. The total number of swaps needed to reach the final position (for this permutation) is seven.

Next, it is easy to explain why this algorithm gets the cups into position in the fewest possible swaps.  Notice that no matter which way we swap the cups, eventually cups $3$ and $2$ will have to swap sides from one another, as will $3$ and $1$.  So, each of those swaps was inevitable.  Indeed, all of the swaps in the "left-swap" algorithm are inevitable.

However, it is important to point out to the students that the order of the swaps was **not** inevitable.  Indeed, we could have performed a symmetrically defined "right-swap" algorithm, also in seven moves.

Now, the key point to proving that the sign function is a group homomorphism really boils down to the fact that if we add one more swap, such as swapping cups $4$ and $7$ to get the new line-up
$$
\begin{matrix}3 & 5& 2& 1& 7 & 4& 6 &8 \end{matrix},
$$
then the minimum number of swaps needed to reach this new permutation has changed by one. (In other words, the parity of the minimum number of swaps has changed.)

Here is the easy idea of the proof.  First note that the "left-swap" algorithm in both cases begins by making exactly the same swaps for the cups $3,5,2,1$.  So, we might as well ignore those cups, and show that the minimum number of swaps going from
$$
\begin{matrix}4 & 6 & 7 &8 \end{matrix}
$$
to
$$
\begin{matrix}4 & 7 & 6 &8 \end{matrix}
$$
is one different than the minimum number of swaps when instead going to
$$
\begin{matrix}7 & 4 & 6 &8\end{matrix}.
$$
But now, using the "right-swap" algorithm, we can also ignore cups $6$ and $8$.  So, it really boils down to the fact that in the first case we didn't need to swap $4$ and $7$, but in the second case we did.  So in this case, the minimum number of swaps increases by one.  (Of course, if we had chosen different cups to swap, it might have had the opposite effect, so that there was one less swap needed.)

---

There are some other reasons I really like this "cup" approach.  It makes it easy to explain Cayley's theorem, and other "renaming" theorems.  If you use another eight cups labelled  $1,r,r^2, r^3,s,rs,r^2s,r^3s$, then you can explain how $D_8$ acts on the cups, and gives a permutation representation in $S_8$.  Just put the new cups on top of the original cups, and see that they also get permuted, then take the new cups off and see how the old numbers were permuted.  Of course, this cup method shouldn't be used exclusively, as sometimes it is hard for people to think visually.  In fact, I think it is most helpful *after* they already know that permutations are products of transpositions.

Comment: Such a simple and effective explanation, really good

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out to break down your steps and thought process without skipping steps! Your details are much appreciated

Answer (score 13):

Obviously, there are lots of answers already, but I thought I'd give the proof of (5) as given by Jordan already in 1870 in his *Traité des substitutions* -- this has the benefit of being quite clear to read, and cuts directly into the "conceptual".

The following is my translation of his Theorem 77, its proof, and the paragraph above it (pp. 64--65), with some update of the words used (e.g. permutation instead of "substitution"):

> A cycle on $p$ letters $a, b, c, \dots$ is clearly the product of the $p-1$ transpositions $(ab), (ac), \dots$. Hence an arbitrary permutation on $k$ letters and containing $n$ cycles is the product of $k-n$ transpositions.
>
> **Theorem:** Let $S, T$ be two permutations which are respectively the product of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ transpositions. The number of successive transpositions in the product $ST$ is even or odd, according as to whether $\alpha + \beta$ is even or odd.
>
> **Proof:** As any permutation is the product of transpositions, it suffices to show the theorem when $T$ is a transposition, in which case $\beta = 1$.
>
> To make the idea clear, let $S = (abcde)(fg)$. If $T$ transposes two letters which appear in the same cycle, such as $a$ and $c$, then we have
> $$ ST = (ab)(cde)(fg), $$
> which is a permutation containing one cycle more than $S$, and which, accordingly, is a product of $\alpha-1$ transpositions. If on the other hand $T$ transposes two letters $a, f$ appearing in different cycles, then $ST=(abcdefg)$ will contain one cycle less than $S$, and will hence be the product of $\alpha+1$ transpositions. In either case, the number of transpositions in the product $ST$ will be congruent to $\alpha + 1 \pmod 2$.

I think this counts more as the "traditional" proof than the determinant-proof, as it appears in the first book on group theory ever published :-) Of course, it does fall into "Using a decomposition into disjoint cycles, one can simply compute what happens when multiplying by a transposition", but it doesn't strike me as magic (and I don't think it struck Jordan as magic either!)

Comment: I guess this is the first proof of this result, since Galois didn't work with alternating groups. A more verbose/modern/student-friendly version of Jordan's proof is in Rotman, "An Introduction to the Theory of Groups", pp. 7-9.

Comment: I think that this proof becomes clearer if you draw a picture of a cycle and how it breaks in two when multiplied by a transposition, and also how two cycles get joined when their product is multiplied by a transposition.

Answer (score 13):

Is the inversion counting argument really so magical? Let me write it out and you can point out which step seems unmotivated.

An unordered pair $\{i,j\}$ is an inversion of $\sigma$ if $\sigma(i)$ and $\sigma(j)$ are ordered in the opposite manner to $i$ and $j$. Thinking of computing $\{\pi(\sigma(i)), \pi(\sigma(j))\}$ in two steps, namely $\{i,j\} \mapsto \{\sigma(i), \sigma(j)\} \mapsto \{\pi(\sigma(i)), \pi(\sigma(j))\}$, we see the following equivalence which I claim is really the heart of the matter:

$\{i,j\}$ is an inversion of  $\pi \circ \sigma$ if and only if exactly one the following statements is true:

- $\{i,j\}$ is an inversion of $\sigma$.
- $\{\sigma(i), \sigma(j)\}$ is an inversion of $\pi$.

This means that the set of inversions $I(\sigma)$ satisfies $I(\pi \circ \sigma) = I(\sigma) \mathbin\triangle \sigma^{-1}(I(\pi))$, where $\triangle$ denotes symmetric difference. Then taking parities of cardinalities, we get that $\#I : S_n \to \mathbb{Z}/2$ is a homomorphism.

Answer (score 10):

This answer grew out of an attempt to understand the polynomial product formula in David Speyer's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/417692/82179) (also Theo Johnson-Freyd's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined/417693#comment1071992_417690)). It has been superseded by Bjorn Poonen's excellent self-contained [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/417732/82179).

If $T$ is a totally ordered set of $n$ elements, the product in Speyer's answer is defined in terms of the section to
$$T^2 \setminus \Delta_T \to {T \choose 2}$$
taking $S \subseteq T$ to $(\min(S),\max(S))$, but clearly does not depend on the choice of this section (swapping a pair of indices induces a $-1$ on the top and bottom). This is reminiscent of a *norm* or *corestriction* in group cohomology. An [earlier version](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/417719/4) of my answer worked this out in a more general setting using cocycles and crossed homomorphisms, but thanks to Poonen's answer and Benjamin Steinberg's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined/417692#comment1072566_417719), I can now do this without using cocycles.

If $S$ and $T$ are finite sets, then $S(T) \times S(S)$ acts on $X = \operatorname{Inj}(S,T)$ by post- and precomposition. The action of $S(S)$ is free since injections are monic, and we denote the quotient $X/S(S)$ by $Y={T \choose S}$. Concretely, we want $\lvert S\rvert = 2$ and $\lvert T \rvert = n$ to get $S_n \times S_2$ acting on $\operatorname{Inj}(2,T) \cong T^2 \setminus \Delta_T$. This is an example of the following more general object:

**Setup.** Let $G$ and $A$ be groups (eventually $A$ will be abelian), let $X$ be a set with a $(G \times A)$-action such that the $A$-action is free, and set $Y = X/A$. Equivalently, $\pi \colon X \to Y$ is a $G$-equivariant $A$-torsor, in the sense that $\pi$ is a $G$-equivariant map of $G$-sets such that
\begin{align*}
\mu \colon A \times X &\to X \underset Y\times X \\
(a,x) &\mapsto (ax,x)
\end{align*}
is a $G$-equivariant bijection, where $G$ acts trivially on $A$. In other words, this is an $\underline{A}$-torsor on the slice category $G\text{-}\mathbf{Set}/Y$, where $\underline{A}$ is the 'constant object' on $A$ (the pullback of $A$ from the terminal Grothendieck topos $\mathbf{Set}$).

The internal hom $\mathbf{Hom}_Y(Y,{-}) \colon G\text{-}\mathbf{Set}/Y \to G\text{-}\mathbf{Set}$ preserves limits, so takes the above to the $A^Y$-torsor $\mathbf{Hom}_Y(Y,X)$ of sections to $\pi$ (this is the torsor in Poonen's answer). Here, $A^Y$ is no longer a constant object: it has a natural $G$-action. Such a torsor corresponds to an element $\phi \in H^1(G,A^Y)$ (nonabelian cohomology, although we will now assume $A$ is abelian), i.e. a *crossed homomorphism* $\phi \colon G \to A^Y$. Given a section $s \colon Y \to X$ of $\pi$, the crossed homomorphism $\phi \colon G \to A^Y$ can be computed via the composition
$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}G & \to & X \underset Y\times X & \stackrel\sim\leftarrow & A \times X & \stackrel{\pi_1}\to & A \\ g & \mapsto & (gs(y),s(gy)).\! & & & & \end{array}$$
In other words, $\phi(g)(y)$ is the unique $a \in A$ such that $gs(y) = as(gy)$. Different choices of section give crossed homomorphisms that differ by a principal crossed homomorphism.

If $A$ is abelian and $Y$ finite, then there is a ($G$-equivariant) multiplication map $\Pi \colon A^Y \to A$, giving a map $H^1(\Pi) \colon H^1(G,A^Y) \to H^1(G,A)$. Since the $G$-action on $A$ is trivial, this is just $\operatorname{Hom}(G,A)$, so $H^1(\Pi)(\phi)$ is a homomorphism $G \to A$.

In the case of $S_n \times S_2$ $\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{\circlearrowright}$ $\!\operatorname{Inj}(2,n)$, this gives a homomorphism $S_n \to S_2$. Given a section $s \colon {T \choose 2} \to T^2 \setminus \Delta_T$, write $s_1, s_2 \colon {T \choose 2} \to T$ for the projections $\pi_i \circ s$. Then the crossed homomorphism $\phi \colon S_n \to \{\pm 1\}^{T \choose 2}$ can be identified with
$$\phi(\sigma)(S) = \frac{x_{\sigma(s_1(S))}-x_{\sigma(s_2(S))}}{x_{s_1(\sigma(S))}-x_{s_2(\sigma(S))}}.$$
Taking the product over all $S \in {T \choose 2}$ recovers the formula in Speyer's answer when $s$ is given by $S \mapsto (\min(S),\max(S))$.

**Remark.** One thing I still find weird about this is that it *almost* works to give a homomorphism $S_n \to S_3$ as well, by taking $\operatorname{Inj}(3,n)$ instead of $\operatorname{Inj}(2,n)$. It somehow only fails because $S_3$ is not abelian.  Replacing $S_3$ by its subgroup $C_3$ does give a homomorphism $S_n \to C_3$, which presumably is trivial. But somehow for $C_2 = S_2$ the map is nontrivial!

---

**Relation to corestriction.**

If the $G$-action on $Y$ is transitive, then choosing a point $y \in Y$ gives an isomorphism $G/H \stackrel\sim\to Y$ of $G$-sets, where $H = \operatorname{Stab}_G(y)$. Left Kan extension
\begin{align*}
H\text{-}\mathbf{Set} &\to G\text{-}\mathbf{Set} \\
Z &\mapsto (G \times Z)/H \cong \coprod_{G/H} Z
\end{align*}
identifies $H\text{-}\mathbf{Set}$ with the slice topos $G\text{-}\mathbf{Set}/Y$, and $A^Y$ is the coinduction of the trivial $H$-module $A$. For $\lvert Y\rvert = [G:H]$ finite, this is also the induction, so Shapiro's lemma says that
$$H^1(G,A^Y) \cong H^1(H,A) = \operatorname{Hom}(H,A).$$
The map $H^1(H,A) \to H^1(G,A)$ in this case is called *corestriction*.

The homomorphism $H \to A$ can be deduced immediately from the Setup: if $x \in X$ is a lift of $y$, then
$$\operatorname{Stab}_{G \times A}(x) \to \operatorname{Stab}_G(y) = H$$
is an isomorphism, so its inverse gives a projection $H \to A$. In our main example, the point $\{1,2\} \in {T \choose 2}$ has stabiliser $H = S_2 \times S_{n-2} \subseteq S_n$, and the above shows that the sign $S_n \to S_2$ is the corestriction of the projection $H \to S_2$.

Comment: The approach [described](https://mathoverflow.net/a/417692) by @DavidE.Speyer was earlier mentioned by @‍TheoJohnson-Freyd in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined/417693#comment1071992_417690).

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for the call-out, but David gives many more details. And I assume it is what Tim had in mind with his rejection of things about polynomials.

Comment: If you view $f$ as a map $G\to A^Y$ via currying, and you view $A^Y$ as a $G$-module in the obvious way (when $A$ is abelian) then you do have a crossed homomorphism.  This is is what is used in my write up using wreath products.  Then the $G$-module homomorphism $A^Y\to A$ which sends $f$ to $\prod_{y\in Y}f(y)$ is a $G$-module homomorphism where $A$ is a trivial $G$-module and so gives a homomorphism $H^1(G,A^Y)\to H^1(G,A)$ that  is your homomorphism.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg oh much better. That's also closer to Poonen's answer, where $A^Y$ and the multiplication map $A^Y \to A$ are the key players.

Comment: I made it a new CW answer but I think it is basically the same as yours.  $A^Y$ just got hidden in your proof because you didn't curry.

Answer (score 10):

The symmetric group can be thought of as automorphisms of the boundary of $n$-simplex, and whether the permutation is even depends on whether it reverses orientation, as others have pointed out. The boundary of the $n$-simplex can be thought of as the ($n-1$)-dimensional sphere up to homotopy equivalence. And so the result would follow from the fact that there are two connected components of the space of automorphisms of spheres with $n$ at least $2$.

Edit: Now I guess I would like to address the issue that perhaps it is not clear automorphisms of the sphere fall in two components. Here I propose an intuition which is not necessarily elementary. I propose to think of the automorphisms of the sphere inducing automorphisms of the sphere spectrum. Then accepting that the sphere spectrum discretized looks like the integers; I would claim that this gives an intuition that the automorphisms fall in two components using the fact that the integers only has two automorphisms as a group.

Comment: As you say, others have pointed this out (notably [@WillBrian](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1071995) and, in reference to orthogonal groups, [@TheoJohnson-Freyd](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1071984)), and the questioner has indicated ([1](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1071986) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1072005)) that this approach is not yet satisfactory to them.

Comment: Ah yes i didn't read all the comments carefully sorry. Then this answer contains nothing more than the comment of @Theo

Answer (score 10):

Not the most pedagogical, but I think this counts as "conceptual": it comes down to the fact that a hyperplane separates space into exactly two components.

As has been pointed out in many previous answers, we can get the $\operatorname{sgn}$ homomorphism from $\operatorname{det}$.

We can get $\operatorname{det}$ conceptually by thinking about the topology of $\operatorname{O}(n)$. We know that the connected component of the identity, $\operatorname{SO}(n)$, is a normal subgroup, so we get a surjective map $\operatorname{det}:\operatorname{O}(n) \rightarrow \operatorname{O}(n)/ \operatorname{SO}(n) = \operatorname{G}$ where $\operatorname{G}$ has size equal to the number of connected components. Once we know that there are exactly two components, $\operatorname{G}$ must be $\mathbb{Z}/2$

The usual way to analyze the topology of $\operatorname{O}(n)$ is by fibering, i.e. thinking of the columns of each matrix as an orthogonal basis, and projecting the set of orthogonal bases onto the set of sets of $k$ orthogonal vectors for $ 1 \leq k \leq n$.

Let $\operatorname{Fr}(n,k)$ denote the space of $k$-tuples of orthogonal unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e. tuples that could be the first $k$ columns of a matrix in $\operatorname{O}(n)$). Then we have a surjective map $\pi_k : \operatorname{Fr}(n,k) \rightarrow \operatorname{Fr}(n,k-1)$ given by forgetting the last vector. The fiber of this map over any point is homotopic to $S^{n-k}$. So arguing by induction, for $k < n$, we have that $\operatorname{Fr}(n,k)$ is connected since $\operatorname{Fr}(n,k-1)$ and $S^{n-k}$ are.

To really complete the proof, you have to be more careful about analyzing the topology of $\operatorname{O}(n)$ to show that the fibration in the last step is not a nontrivial double cover. This should be pretty straightforward since $\pi_1(\operatorname{Fr}(n, n - 1))$ has to be generated by the $S^1$ that appears as the fiber of the map $\pi_{n - 1}$, so you can write it down and check the action on the fiber of the map $\pi_{n}$

Alternatively, if you just want to get the correct number of connected components, I think the following works (for $\operatorname{GL}(n)$ instead of $\operatorname{O}(n)$): using row reduction and the fact that matrices $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & k \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $diag(1,...,k,...,1)$ for $k > 0$ are in the connected component of the identity, you can explicitly construct a path from any matrix to some diagonal matrix with only $1$ and $-1$ on the diagonal. Then since $\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ is in the connected component of the identity, you can connect any matrix to a diagonal matrix with only $1$ and at most one $-1$ on the diagonal. This gives that there are at most two components. Then you still need to show that there are two separate components, which you can do by defining $\hat{\operatorname{det}}$ as the sign of the product of the multi-set of eigenvalues. Of course you need to somehow show that the multi-set of eigenvalues depends continuously on the matrix, but I think this is possible to do without introducing the polynomial expression for the determinant. But you specifically do not need to know that $\hat{\operatorname{det}}$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: "In this way it is straightforward to see that the set of sets of n−1 orthogonal vectors is connected" - I don't see how

Comment: Edited, hopefully I've clarified things.

Comment: It seems to me that it's easier to do induction on the bundle $O(n-1)\to O(n)\to S^{n-1}$. From the long exact homotopy sequence it follows that the inclusion $O(n-1)\to O(n)$ gives a bijection on $\pi_0$ if $n\ge 3$. This reduces everything to $O(2)$ which is easy to deal with by hand.

Answer (score 9):

$\DeclareMathOperator\sgn{sgn}$How about arguing by induction?  I claim that there is a homomorphism map $\sgn_n : \Sigma_n \to \{\pm1\}$ that takes the value $-1$ at every transposition.  This is vacuously true for $n = 0$ and $n = 1$.

In general, suppose that $n$ is greater than $1$ and we have such a map $\sgn_{n - 1}$ on $\Sigma_{n - 1}$.

Let $\tau$ be the transposition that swaps $n$ and $n - 1$.  Since $\Sigma_n$ equals $\Sigma_{n - 1} \sqcup \Sigma_{n - 1}\tau\Sigma_{n - 1}$, and since two elements of $\Sigma_{n - 1}$ that are conjugate by $\tau$ are already conjugate in $\Sigma_{n - 1}$ (so that $\sgn_{n - 1}$ agrees on them), there is a unique function $\sgn_n : \Sigma_n \to \{\pm1\}$ that transforms by $\sgn_{n - 1}$ under left and right translation by $\Sigma_{n - 1}$, and that takes the value $1$ at $1$ and $-1$ at $\tau$.  Since all transpositions that move $n$ are conjugate under $\Sigma_{n - 1}$, the map $\sgn_n$ is independent of the choice of $\tau$.

I originally thought that it was obvious that $\sgn_n$ was a homomorphism, and said:

> It's hard to imagine your, or anyone's, liking this argument better than the one proposed by @TheoJohnsonFreyd in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined/417693#comment1071992_417690) or by @DavidESpeyer in the [answers](https://mathoverflow.net/a/417692), but I think it doesn't violate any of your interdicts.

… but now I see that some computation has to be done, which was at least tacitly ruled out.  Oh well!

It is clear that $\sgn_n(\sigma)^{-1}\sgn_n(\sigma\bullet)$ equals $\sgn_n$ for all $\sigma \in \Sigma_{n - 1}$; and that $\sgn_n(\tau)^{-1}\sgn_n(\tau\bullet)$ equals $1$ at $1$ and $-1$ at $\tau$, and transforms by $\sgn_{n - 1}$ under left translation by $\Sigma_{n - 2}$ and right translation by $\Sigma_{n - 1}$.  It thus remains only to show that $\sgn_n(\tau)^{-1}\sgn_n(\tau\bullet)$ agrees with $\sgn_n$ at every element of the form $\sigma\tau$, where $\sigma \in \Sigma_{n - 1}$ is a transposition that moves $n - 1$.  The braid relations—mentioned in one of your bullet points as a possible acceptable line of attack—say that $\tau\sigma\tau$ equals $\sigma\tau\sigma$.  Thus, $\sgn_n(\tau)^{-1}\sgn_n(\tau\sigma\tau)$ equals $-\sgn_n(\sigma\tau\sigma) = \sgn_{n - 1}(\sigma)\sgn_{n - 1}(\sigma)\sgn_n(\tau)\sgn_{n - 1}(\sigma) = \sgn_n(\sigma\tau)$.

Comment: As is probably obvious, this is clumsily inspired by the Hopf-algebra approach to the representation theory of the symmetric groups.

Comment: Extending your comment: the involution that sends a Schur function $s_{\lambda}$ to $s_{\lambda^t}$ -- and hence the trivial representation to the sign representation -- is (essentially: maybe there's a sign) the antipode in the Hopf algebra of symmetric functions. I wonder if this observation could somehow be used to prove the existence of the sign representation.

Comment: @SamHopkins, [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined#comment1072026_417693) would be very appealing!  If you figure it out, then I hope you'll post it as an answer!

Comment: @Vincent, thank you for fixing my typo.

Answer (score 8):

The following framing of statement 4 from the list of equivalent statements allows you to shift what I presume is the "not-terrible computation" to another place:

4'. The identity permutation $(1) \in \Sigma_n$ is not the product of an odd number of swaps.

A *swap* here is a transposition of the form $(i\; (i+1))$.

Proof of 4': In any ordering of $1,2,\ldots, n$, if you swap the two integers at positions $i$ and $i+1$, it changes the number of inversions by exactly $1$, since only the relative order between the integers at those positions is affected. (An inversion is a pair $(a,b)$ with $a>b$.) If we start with the list in order and apply an odd number of swaps, we thus end up with an odd number of inversions. But the identity permutation has 0 inversions. $\Box$

The 'conceptual reason,' then: a swap changes 'how wrong' an ordering is by exactly $1$, and so we can't use an odd number of them on $1,2,\ldots,n$ in order to get back to having $0$ pairs in the wrong order.

That 4 and 4' are equivalent follows from the fact that any transposition $(ij)$ can be written as a product of an odd number of swaps. You can write this down explicitly: $(ij) = \cdots((i+1)\;(i+2))\; (i\; (i+1))$ (if $i<j$). Or you can maybe see it intuitively: move $i$ over to $j$ by swaps, and then move $j$ to where $i$ was, which needs $1$ fewer moves since it's already been shifted once. In any case, this is where the computation is. But maybe this is a preferable place to have it.

Answer (score 7):

For my taste, an accidentally discovered proof of the well-definedness of "parity of number adjacent transpositions to express a permutation" can arise in attempting to clarify/simplify proofs about (not only spherical and affine) buildings acted upon by naturally-arising groups (especially "classical groups").

The critical point can be expressed in orthodox terms: that the *length* $\ell(s\cdot w)$ of $s\cdot w$, in a Coxeter group $W$ with specified reflexion-generators $S$, with $w\in W$ and $s\in S$, is $\ell(w)\pm 1$. Never $\ell(w)$ again. In particular, the parity flips, exactly.

Some orthodox treatments of this are unsatisfying to *me*, because they presume combinatorial things exactly like proving that permutations have well-defined parities.

Likewise, some developments of "buildings" depend crucially on developing lots of combinatorial theory of Coxeter groups first.

On another hand, a theorem of J. Tits showed that the automorphism groups of apartments in "thick" buildings *are* Coxeter groups. That is, the apartments are Coxeter complexes...

The argument for that is not trivial, but it *does* have more of the geometric/conceptual flavor that one might like. After studying the orthodox version for a while, a few years ago I realized that the same sort of "geometric" building-theoretic arguments could prove that crucial $\ell(s\cdot w)=\ell(w)\pm 1$ property directly. See [http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/bldgs.pdf](http://www.math.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/v/bldgs.pdf) for a self-contained discussion of this and other corollaries of a somewhat stubbornly-impatient attitude about it (also, similarly, refined aspects of Bruhat decompositions...)

... oop, and forgot to mention that realizing permutation groups as the apartment automorphism groups for the (thick) building constructed from subspaces of a vectorspace over a field is pretty easy.

Answer (score 6):

There are already enough answers but here is a rewrite of Poonen's and De Bruyn's answer in the language of wreath products.

Let $A$ be a group acting freely on the right of a finite set $X$.  Then $\mathrm{Aut}_A(X)$ is well known to be isomorphic to the permutational wreath product $A\wr \mathrm{Sym}(X/A)=A^{X/A}\rtimes \mathrm{Sym}(X/A)$.  The isomorphism depends on choosing a transversal for $X/A$ but any two isomorphisms are conjugate by an element of $A^{X/A}$.  In concrete terms, choose a section $t\colon X/A\to X$ and send $f\in \mathrm{Aut}_A(X)$ to $(F,f')$ where $f'$ is the permutation of $X/A$ induced by $f$ and $F\colon X/A\to A$ is defined on $e\in X/A$ by $f(t(e))=t(f'(e))F(e)$.  If $t'\colon X/A\to X$ is another section, then there is $h\in A^{X/A}$ such that $t'(e)=t(e)h(e)$ for all $e\in X/A$ and the isomorphism constructed from $t'$ is conjugate to the one constructed from $t$ by $(h,1)\in A\wr \mathrm{Sym}(X/A)$.  I didn't give the inverse of the isomorphism because it is not needed to construct the sign map.

In the case $A$ is abelian, there is a homomorphism $\tau_0\colon A^{X/A}\rtimes \mathrm{Sym}(X/A)\to A$ given by $(f,\sigma)\mapsto \prod_{e\in X/A}f(e)$ (sometimes called the transfer map). This gives a homomorphism $\tau\colon \mathrm{Aut}_A(X)\to A$ which is independent of the isomorphism  constructed above since isomorphisms coming from different sections (i.e. transversals) differ by an inner automorphism and $A$ is abelian.

Now consider the group $A=C_2$ (the two element cyclic group) and consider the set $E$ of distinct pairs of elements from $[n]=\{1,\ldots, n\}$.  Then $C_2$ acts freely on the right of $E$ by having the nontrivial element switching the coordinates and the action of $S_n$ on $E$ commutes with this. We then the composed homomorphism $S_n\to \mathrm{Aut}_{C_2}(E)\xrightarrow{\,\tau\,} C_2$.

As usual we just then need to check the transposition $(1,2)$ is sent to the nontrivial element of $C_2$, but this follows easily if you choose as your transversal the ordered pairs $(i,j)$ with $i<j$ and follow through the construction.

Answer (score 6):

Seems to be really addictive, so you will have to endure one more answer I am afraid.

What follows is actually present in several of already given answers, I am just trying to make it as simple as possible.

Write down $\binom n2$ statements "$1<2$", "$1<3$", ..., "$n-1<n$".

Now perform a permutation and count how many of these statements will become violated.

If this permutation is a transposition  $(ij)$, for $i<j$, then those violated are all "$i<k$" with $k<j$, all "$\ell<j$" with $\ell>i$ (same number twice), and "$i<j$". So each transposition violates an odd number of these statements.

Viewing result of a permutation as a reordering, we see that performing one more transposition switches between "even violators" and "odd violators".

I believe this suffices to convince oneself that parity of the number of transpositions producing any given permutation (unlike the number itself) is unambiguously defined, and coincides with parity of the number of those violations.

Comment: But in this formulation, it is not clear that this is a group homomorphism!

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Hmm is not it at least clear that parity of the number of involved transpositions is unambiguously defined and equal to the parity of the number of violations?

Comment: I think this is a fine argument, but I will note that it is already mentioned in the original question, as "Defining the sign homomorphism in terms of the number of pairs whose order is swapped likewise boils down to a not-terrible computation to see that the sign function is a homomorphism. But it still feels like magic."

Comment: I like this description. It's basically decoding some of the other answers into plain language.

Comment: @SridharRamesh Well, I tried to make it look less magic. Maybe I omitted some essential step, I am not sure anymore to be honest...

Answer (score 6):

This is really a variation on [manzana’s answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/417828/1345) to show $O(n)$ has two components, but I wanted to describe it in the way that I think about orientations.

We may think of an element of $O(n)$ as an orthonormal frame $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$, $|v_i|=1$, $v_i\cdot v_j=0, i\neq j$, giving an orientation of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For $n>1$, we may rotate the first $n-1$ vectors to $e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0), e_2=(0,1,0,\ldots,0), \ldots, e_{n-1}=(0,\ldots,0,1,0)$. To do this, rotate the first vector
$v_1$ to $e_1$, which we may do since $S^{n-1}$ is connected (and rotating the rest of the frame along at each step). Then rotate $v_2$ to $e_2$ while keeping $e_1$ fixed using that the sphere $S^{n-2}=S^{n-1}\cap e_1^\perp$ is connected, and so on until we get to rotate $v_{n-1}$ to $e_{n-1}$ keeping $e_1,\ldots, e_{n-2}$ fixed using $S^1$ is connected. Moreover, this rotation is canonical and sends $v_n$ to $\pm e_n$. Thus we see that $O(n)$ has two components, and the determinant is the sign of the last vector in the orthogonal frame that we have rotated to.

Of course, to prove this rigorously (to see that we indeed get two components), one must proceed by induction on dimension and use a fibration as in manzana’s answer. But I thought I would point out that this is how I (and maybe others) intuitively / pictorially think about orientations of $\mathbb{R}^n$ via the components of the space of $n$-frames.

[image: rotation of othonormal frame to standard one.]

Answer (score 5):

Here is another variation on the other answers (particularly, the Cartier approach).  Let $G$ be a group acting on the left of a finite set $X$, let $A$ an abelian group and let $c\colon G\times X\to A$ be a "$1$-cocycle", meaning that $c(gh,x) = c(g,hx)c(h,x)$ for all $x\in X$ and $g,h\in H$.   You can then define a homomorphism $\theta\colon G\to A$ by the rule $$\theta(g) = \prod_{x\in X}c(g,x).$$  Although we are supposed to rule out computation, this is easy:  $$\theta(gh)=\prod_{x\in X}c(gh,x)=\prod_{x\in X}c(g,hx)c(h,x) =\prod_{y\in X}c(g,y)\prod_{x\in X}c(h,x) =\theta(g)\theta(h)$$ by putting $y=hx$.

Now apply this to $S_n$ acting on the set $X$ of $2$-element subsets of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ with $A=\{\pm 1\}$.  For $i<j$, put
$$c(\sigma,\{i,j\})= \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if}\ \sigma(i)<\sigma(j)\\ -1, &\text{if}\ \sigma(i)>\sigma(j)\end{cases}$$ (so $c$ checks if $\sigma$ inverts $\{i,j\}$) and observe that the $1$-cocycle condition just says that $\sigma\tau$ inverts $i,j$ if and only if exactly one of $\tau$ inverting $i,j$ and $\sigma$ inverting $\tau(i),\tau(j)$ occurs.  Then $c((1,2),\{i,j\})=-1$ iff $\{i,j\}=\{1,2\}$ and so $\theta((1,2))=-1$.

**Categorical remark.** In categorical terms, you can build the transformation groupoid (aka Grothendieck construction, aka category of elements) $G\ltimes X$ and a $1$-cocycle is precisely a functor, that is, an element of $H^1(G\ltimes X,A)\cong H^1(G,A^X)$ (by Shapiro's lemma), the latter of which maps to $H^1(G,A)$ via the augmentation $A^X\to A$ sending $f$ to $\prod_{x\in X}f(x)$ like in my other answer. In fancier terms, $B(G\ltimes X)$ is the finite sheet covering space of $BG$ corresponding to the $G$-set $X$, and so you can use the transfer map to get $\mathrm{Hom}(G\ltimes X,A)\cong H^1(B(G\ltimes X),A)\to H^1(BG,A)\cong \mathrm{Hom}(G,A)$.

**Topological remark.**  As essentially mentioned in DeBruyn's latest version of his answer (in categorical language), we can view this all topologically (but then I get switched to right actions).  Let $BS_n$ be the classifying space of $S_n$ built via the bar construction. Let $X$ the right $S_n$-set of all two-element subsets of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$.  Then this is a transitive $S_n$-set so corresponds to a connected finite sheet covering $E\to BS_n$ whose fundamental group is isomorphic to a stabilizer, which in turn is isomorphic to $S_2\times S_{n-2}$. Moreover, $E$ is a classifying space for its fundamental group since its universal covering space, that of $BS_n$, is contractible. Since $H^1(S_2\times S_{n-2},\{\pm 1\})$ is obviously nontrivial via the projection to $S_2$, this gives a nontrivial $1$-cocycle $c$ on $E$.  Edges of $E$ look like $(e,\sigma)\colon e\to e\sigma$ where $e\in X$, $\sigma \in S_n$ and the corresponding $2$-cocycle gives $-1$ if $\sigma$ inverts $e$ and $1$, else.  Now the transfer map sends this cocycle to an element of $H^1(BS_n,\{\pm 1\})=\mathrm{Hom}(S_n,\{\pm 1\})$ which is easily verified by the construction of transfer to send $\sigma$ to the product of the $c(e,\sigma)$ over all $e$, which is $-1$ raised to the number of inversions.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a slightly more geometric version of the arguments given that has more of a Coxeter group feel.  It boils down though to Cartier's argument but orientations of the complete graph are replaced by considering the corresponding graphical hyperplane arrangement.

Let $\mathcal A_n$ be the braid arrangement in $\mathbb R^n$.  It consists of the $\binom{n}{2}$ hyperplanes $$H_{ij} = \{\vec x\in \mathbb R^n\mid x_i=x_j\}$$ with $i\neq j$.

The group $S_n$ acts on $\mathbb R^n$ by permuting the coordinates and this action permutes $\mathcal A_n$.  Let $\vec p=(1,2,3,\cdots, n)$ and note that $\vec p\notin H_{ij}$ for all $i,j$.  Let $X$ be the orbit $S_n\cdot \vec p$; it consists of $n!$-distinct elements, none of which belong to any $H_{ij}$.

For $\vec q, \vec r\in X$, put $s(\vec q,\vec r)$ to be the number of hyperplanes in $\mathcal A_n$ separating $\vec q,\vec r$, where a hyperplane separates these vectors if they are in different connected components of the complement (of which there are two).  Put $d(\vec q,\vec r)=(-1)^{s(\vec q,\vec r)}$.

Easy facts:

1. $d(\vec q,\vec r)=d(\vec r,\vec q)$ (immediate)
2. $d(\sigma(\vec q),\sigma(\vec r)) =d(\vec q,\vec r)$ for $\sigma\in S_n$ since $\mathcal A_n$ is permuted by $S_n$.
3. $d(\vec q,\vec r)d(\vec r,\vec s)=d(\vec q,\vec s)$ because a hyperplane separates $\vec q$ and $\vec s$ if and only if it separates exactly one of $\vec q,\vec r$ and $\vec r,\vec s$ because hyperplane complements have two connected components.

From this we can define $$\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) = d(\sigma (\vec q),\vec q)$$ where $\vec q\in X$.  This is independent of $\vec q$ because $$d(\sigma(\vec r), \vec r)=d(\sigma(\vec r),\sigma(\vec q))d(\sigma(\vec q),\vec q)d(\vec q,\vec r) = d(\sigma(\vec q),\vec q)$$ by 1,2 and 3 above.

It is a homomorphism because $$\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma\tau)=d(\sigma\tau(\vec q),\vec q) =d(\sigma\tau(\vec q),\tau(\vec q))d(\tau(\vec q),\vec q) = \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)\mathrm{sgn}(\tau)$$ by 3 and independence of $\mathrm{sgn}$ on the choice of $\vec q$.

Finally, if $\sigma=(1,2)$, then $\sigma(\vec p) = (2,1,3,\ldots, n)$ and so only $H_{1,2}$ separates $\vec p$ and $\sigma(\vec p)$.  Thus $\mathrm{sgn(\sigma)}=-1$.

This can be identified with Speyer's answer by just observing that $f(\vec x)=x_i-x_j$ is a form defining $H_{ij}$ and so $$d(\sigma \vec p,\vec p) =\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\dfrac{\sigma(j)-\sigma(i)}{j-i}.$$

Comment: And note that the polynomial $\Delta:=\prod_{i<j } (x_i - x_j)$ is positive on the $A_n$ chambers and negative on the non-$A_n$ chambers. This polynomial is very motivated in this context; it is the minimal polynomial (up to sign) which vanishes on all the hyperplanes.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined#comment1072020_417690) by Benjamin Steinberg, saying that

*"Usually the sign is used to show that the top exterior power is nonzero"*

I think it is possible to turn things around and first prove the existence of non-zero top-forms on an arbitrary $n$-dimensional $K$-vector-space (by induction on $n$, essentially by using Laplace expansion) and extract the sign of permutations from such non-zero top forms by a straightforward group-action:

For $n=1$, the existence of non-zero top forms is vacuously true. So let $n>1$, $V$ an arbitrary $n$-dimensional $K$-vector-space, $\varphi\in V^*\setminus\{0\}$, $\psi\in \varphi^{-1}(\{1\})$ and define the following linear "projection on $\ker \varphi$":
$$P:V \to \ker \varphi : v \mapsto v-\frac{\varphi(v)}{\varphi(\psi)}\psi = v-\varphi(v)\psi.$$
$$\forall j \in \{1,...,n\}:\,P_j:V^n \to (\ker \varphi)^{n-1}: v \mapsto (P(v_1),...,P(v_{j-1}),P(v_{j+1}),...,P(v_n))$$
Since $\ker \varphi$ is an $(n-1)-$dimensional $K$-vector-space, the induction hypothesis implies that there exists a non-zero multi-linear alternating map $\epsilon_{n-1}: (\ker \varphi)^{n-1} \to K$. Then define
$$\epsilon_n: V^n \to K: v \mapsto \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{j+1} \varphi(v_j)\epsilon_{n-1}(P_j(v)).$$
Checking that $\epsilon_n$ is non-zero and multilinear is easy. The "alternation" becomes easy to check after noting that it suffices to prove that $\forall v\in V^n:\,\forall j\in \{1,...,n-1\}:\,v_{j}=v_{j+1}\Rightarrow \epsilon_n(v)=0$.

To proceed to get the sign of permutations, one still has to show that all permutations are compositions of a number of transpositions (maybe of neirest-neighbour-elements $(j,j+1)$). Strictly speaking, for the goal of getting the sign quickly we could have omitted here the proof that $\epsilon_n$ is multilinear, although in that case we have to prove the version of alternation/antisymmetry which says that
$$\forall v\in V^n:\,\forall j\in \{1,...,n-1\}:\, \epsilon_n(v_1,...,v_n)=-\epsilon_n(v_{\pi_{j,j+1}(1)},...,v_{\pi_{j,j+1}(n)}).$$

Comment: This is a great answer.  (It's a bit confusing to use $\psi$ for an element of $V$ rather than of $V^*$ … but maybe that's just my taste in naming vectors.)  What you propose as a sufficient condition for anti-symmetry is, I would argue, the right definition—usually called ‘alternating’—as the only one that carries over sensibly to characteristic $2$; but, of course, in characteristic $2$, one doesn't worry about defining the sign anyway.

Answer (score 4):

*Update 3*: Here is a complete re-write of the arguments given earlier (which are appended below after the horizontal line).

We work over a field $k$ of characteristic different from $2$.

For $i=1,\cdots, n$ let $e_i$ denote the standard basis of the standard inner-product space $V$ of dimension $n$ over $k$.

Given $v\in V$ such that $\langle v,v\rangle\neq 0$ we define
$$
    r_v(x) = x - 2 \frac{\langle x,v\rangle}{\langle v,v\rangle} v
$$ which is the usual definition of a "reflection".

Given $i\neq j$, the reflection $r_{e_i-e_j}$ operates on $V$ by interchanging $e_i$ and $e_j$, and *fixing* $e_k$ for $k$ different from $i$ and $j$.

It follows that the map which sends the transposition $(i,j)$ to $r_{e_i-e_j}$ embeds the permutation group as a subgroup of the group $R(V)$ generated by reflections $r_v$ as $v$ varies.

Let $S(V)$ be the subgroup of $R(V)$ generated by elements of the form $r_v\cdot r_w$.

**Claim**: The group $S(V)$ is of index 2 in $R(V)$.

Consider the space $W=V+k e_0$ as an inner-product space by defining
$$
    \langle v+a e_0, w+b e_0\rangle = \langle v,w\rangle + ab
$$
Clearly, this inner-product *extends* the inner-product on $V$.

If $v\in V$, then $r_v:W\to W$ has the property that it is $r_v:V\to V$ extended by $r_v(e_0)=e_0$.

Further $r_{e_0}(v)=v$ for $v\in V$ and $r_{e_0} \cdot r_v= r_v\cdot r_{e_0}$ for every $v\in V$.

It follows that the group $R(V,W)$ inside automorphisms of $W$ generated by the elements $r_{e_0}\cdot r_v$ acts on $V$ and can be identified with $R(V)$ via this action.

Since $r_{e_0}$ commutes with $r_v$ for every $v$, the subgroup of $R(V,W)$ which acts as *identity* on $e_0$ can be identified under this action with $S(V)$.

This shows that the group $S(V)$ is of index 2 in $R(V)$.

---

A topological argument could go as follows.

The group $\Sigma_n$ acts in an obvious manner on an $(n-1)$-simplex via the action on vertices.

The sign decides whether the action preserves or reverses orientation.

Perhaps this is a circular definition since the question is what is orientation. The answer is that it is something that is preserved under rotations but inverted under reflections.

Put differently, we can play the game of applying rotations to the simplex to try to return the simplex to its original position. Since $3$-cycles are clearly represented by rotations, we see that (the group generated by them) $A_n$ can be applied to the position. Thus, we can transform *any* position using $A_n$ to a position where *all* except two chosen vertices are correctly positioned.

*Update*: Taking up the answer given by manzana one can also argue in terms of the orthogonal group.

The permutation group $\Sigma_n$ operates in a natural way on the $n$-dimensional inner-product space $V$ with a positive definite innner product. One can proceed as follows to study the group $O(V)$ of automorphisms of $V$:

1. Prove by induction that *any* automorphism of $V$ is a product of simple reflections. Let $r_v$ denote the simple reflection that is constant on $v^{\perp}$ and sends $v$ to $-v$.
2. The product $r_v\cdot r_w$ of two reflections is constant on an orthogonal subspace $\{v,w\}^{\perp}$ of codimension 2 and is thus *determined* by what it does on the span of $v$ and $w$.
3. One then shows that if $u$ lies in the plane of $v$ and $w$, then there is a $t$ such that $r_v\cdot r_w = r_t \cdot r_u$. (We can take $t=r_v\cdot r_w(-u)+u$.)
4. It then follows that the subgroup $SO(V)$ of elements of $O(V)$ that are a product of an even number of reflections is a connected group.
5. It also follows that $SO(V)$ is a subgroup of index 2 in $O(V)$.

*Update 2*: In response to the comments and based on the answer given by Timothy Chow, here is another (hopefully simpler) argument.

Let $W$ be an inner-product space of dimension $n+1$ which contains the $n$-dimensional subspace $V$. Let $e_0,e_1,\dots, e_n$ denote the standard basis of $W$.

As above, for a non-zero vector $v$ in $W$, let $r_v$ denote the reflection defined by $r_v(x)=x-2(<x,v>/<v,v>)v$,

For each $0<i,j\leq n$ define automorphisms $R_{i,j}=r_{e_0}\cdot r_{e_i-e_j}$ of $W$. Note that these automorphisms *preserve* $V$ and the action of $R_{i,j}$ on $V$ is exactly the action of the transposition $(i,j)$ as described above. This shows that the group generated by $R_{i,j}$ is $S_n$ via the above action on $V$.

The subgroup of this group that *fixes* $e_0$ is $A_n$. It is clearly of index 2.

Geometrically, the above is an explicit realisation of the group of rigid motions of the "bi-pyramid" that is mentioned in the comment to the answer by Timothy Chow.

Comment: Timothy Chow posted basically the same answer about 10 minutes ago.

Comment: @‍TimothyChow's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/417728) [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined#comment1072122_417730) by @SamHopkins.

Comment: Since the 1-skeleton of the simplex is a complete graph, this is also essentially the same as Bjorn Poonen's answer.

Comment: The "update" is fantastic, and gives a completely satisfying geometric resolution to the problem for me.

Comment: @StevenGubkin: I see the standard argument that $SO_n$ is connected, but I'm not seeing an argument that $O_n$ has at least two components, i.e. why can't you write a reflection as an element of $SO_n$?

Comment: @RyanBudney If $R_u = R_{v}R_{w}$, then we need $u \in \textrm{Span\{v,w\}}$ and by remark (3) we have that there is a $t$ with $R_u = R_u R_t$.  However, this implies $R_t$ is the identity map which it is not.  This shows we cannot write $R_u$ as a product of two reflections.  Will write next comment addressing 4, 6, 8, etc reflections...

Comment: @StevenGubkin Yes, I like this argument too!

Comment: @StevenGubkin: But you can't assume only two reflections.  You can only assume an even number of reflections. It's unclear how this is an improvement on the other arguments.

Comment: @RyanBudney I think I have an argument for even numbers of reflections, but I do not have time to write it up right now.  I think it will fit in a comment.  I will try to write it by tomorrow.

Comment: @RyanBudney The quick argument I thought I had for this has a flaw.  I retract my claim for now, will give it some more thought.

Comment: @StevenGubkin Please see "Update 3". There is a proof now.

Answer (score 4):

It is related to the Steenrod operation $\mathrm{Sq}^2$ vanishing in the cohomology of the sphere spectrum.

This vanishing is witnessed by a spectrum map $\sigma: S \to E$, where $E$ is the fiber of a map $H\mathbb{Z} \to \Sigma^2 H\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ representing $\mathrm{Sq}^2$.  Now, $\Omega^\infty S$ [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barratt%E2%80%93Priddy_theorem) the initial grouplike $E_\infty$-monoid under $N_\bullet \mathrm{FinSet}^\sim$, and the composition $$N_\bullet\mathrm{FinSet}^\sim \to \Omega^\infty S \xrightarrow{\Omega^\infty \sigma} \Omega^\infty E = \mathbb{Z} \times BS_2$$ defines the sign homomorphism.  (Hope I used the modern terminology and notation correctly here, otherwise feel free to improve.)

From this point of view the sign homomorphism is just one special case of a cohomology class $\sigma_p \in H^{2p-3}(BS_n;\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$, defined for each prime number $p$ using vanishing of the Steenrod operation $\mathcal{P}^1$ in the cohomology of the sphere spectrum.

Comment: May I be permitted to plead that this is probably not the answer that will best convince students who are just learning about permutations of the natural-ness of the signum map?

Answer (score 4):

EDIT:  This doesn't work, since orientation is built into the definition of homology.

---

Maybe if I unravel this enough it is actually circular, but I don't think so.

Given an element of $M \in \textrm{GL}_{n+1}(\mathbb{R})$, restrict it to the sphere $\tilde{M}: S^n \to S^n$ via $\tilde{M}(p) = \frac{M(p)}{|M(p)|}$.

$H_n(S^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ by an easy computation. Now just need to check that $\tilde{I}$ gets mapped to $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ while the permutation matrix of a transposition gets sent to $-1$.

Comment: Well you don't need $\pi_n$, you can directly look at $H_n$ :) In fact I think the only way I know how to prove that transpositions are sent to $-1$ without being circular uses $H_n$ rather than $\pi_n$ (and for $H_n$, you can use explicit generating cycles in the singular chain complex of $S^n$, which get mapped to their opposite)

Comment: If you do simplicial homology, then the sign is built into the definition of the action on chains. If you do singular homology, I'm not sure, but I am skeptical that you can get far enough to prove that $H^n_{sing}(S^n)$ is nontrivial without ever introducing the sign of a permutation.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Yes, I guess you are correct about this.  I really love and hate this question.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer : what do you mean ? It seems to me like neither the definition of singular homology nor its computation in the case of $S^n$ involves the sign, can you specify where it would come up ? (I'm probably just missing something)

Comment: I'm probably the one that's wrong; I'll think about it.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I think you are right.  You need to define the sign of the boundary operator on singular simplices, which requires an orientation.

Comment: I don't think it requires an orientation, you just have ordered simplices and you plug in a $(-1)^i$ when you remove the $i$th one. What you have is way stronger than an orientation, it's an ordering (I agree that otherwise, you might as well just talk about oriented simplices)

Answer (score 4):

Here is another rewrite of De Bruyn and Poonen's proof using group cohomology.  This is certainly overpowered.

Let $A$ be an abelian group acting freely on the right of a finite set $X$ and let $G$  act on the left of $X$ via automorphisms of the $A$-action.  Put $Y=X/A$ and note that $A^Y$ is a right $G$-module via precomposition (since $G$ has an induced action on $Y$).  Also, if we make $A$ a trivial right $G$-module, we have a $G$-module homomorphism $\eta\colon A^Y\to A$ given by $\eta(f)=\prod_{y\in Y}f(y)$.

Given a section $t\colon Y\to X$, we get a crossed homomorphism (aka $1$-cocycle) $c\colon G\to A^Y$ by the rule $g(t(y)) = t(gy)c(g)(y)$ using that the action of $G$ on $X$ commutes with the action of $A$.  One easily checks that if you choose a different section, then you get a cohomologous crossed homomorphism and so there is a well defined class $[c]\in H^1(G,A^Y)$ associated to this free action.  Then we have $\eta_*\colon H^1(G,A^Y)\to H^1(G,A)=\mathrm{Hom}(G,A)$ and so $\eta_*([c])$ is a homomorphism $G\to A$.

Let $N=\ker \eta$.  Note that a crossed homomorphism $g\colon G\to A^Y$ that does not take values in $N$ maps to a nontrivial element of $H^1(G,A)=\mathrm{Hom}(G,A)$ under $\eta_*$.

Poonen's answer is of course the case $A=\{\pm 1\}$ acting on the set $X$ of ordered pairs $(i,j)$ with $1\leq i\neq j\leq n$ and then $S_n$ acts on the left of $X$ with the action commuting with $A$.  One can show that the transposition does not map into $N$ under the crossed homomorphism $c$ obtained using the transversal consisting of the $(i,j)$ with $i<j$ since $c((1,2))$ takes on exactly one nontrivial value from $A$. Therefore, $\eta_*([c])$ is a nontrivial homomorphism $S_n\to \{\pm 1\}$ as required.

Answer (score 4):

If they have studied Galois Theory, you could consider the extension of fields $E:= \mathbb{R}(x_1, \ldots, x_n)^{S_n} \subset F:= \mathbb{R}(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ of symmetric rational functions into rational functions. One can play around and try to find a rational function that is "almost symmetric", beside the sign, but not symmetric.

Let's try to find it together. One can start with $x_1-x_2$ and see that it is almost fixed by all the $\sigma$ that swaps $1$ and $2$, but as soon as $1$ is sent to something else, you obtain another difference, e.g. $x_3-x_2$. But hey,if we multiply all such differences, they will be swapped between them, but the product (beside the sign) will be preserved.

Now consider your polynomial $p(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \prod_{i < j} (x_i -x_j)$. Since it is almost symmetric, $p^2$ is symmetric, because the square kills the sign. This means $E(p)$ is a degree $2$ extension of $E$.

On the Galois side, this yields a subgroup $G:= \textrm{Gal}(F/E(p))$ of index $2$. Almost symmetricity of $p$ also implies that $E(p)/E$ is normal, so that we have obtained our normal subgroup $A_n = G$ of $S_n$. It's easy to see that a permutation acts trivially on $p$ if and only if the number of inversions is even.

**Notes.** I am not sure this easily explains *why* $2$ is the right thing, which is better explained by the first answer of character. Existence, however, is explained easily with Galois Theory, with no computation needed. You can give the exercise of finding $p$ for $n=2,3$ and I am sure they will guess (or at least be at ease with) the general formula.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a formula I have not seen in the long and excellent list of answers: If $\sigma\in\mathfrak S_n$, then $\mathop{\rm sgn}(\sigma)=(-1)^{n-p}$, where $p$ is the number of orbits of $\sigma$ on $\{1,\dots,n\}$.

(This definition does even work for a symmetric group on any finite set, and extends to the infinite symmetric group — permutations with finite support.)

The only nonobvious thing is that it defines a morphism of groups. For this, it suffices to prove that if $\tau$ is a transposition, then $\mathop{\rm sgn}(\sigma\tau)=-\mathop{\rm sgn}(\sigma)$. There are two cases, according to which the elements which are swapped by $\tau$ belong to the same orbit, or not. In fact, if $\{a_1,\dots,a_m\}$ is one orbit of $\sigma$, written in cyclic order, and if $\tau=(a_1,a_k)$, with $1<k\le m$, then $\sigma\tau$ has the same orbits as $\sigma$ except that the orbit $(a_1,\dots,a_m)$ is split into two orbits $\{a_1,a_{k+1},\dots,a_m\}$ and $\{a_2,\dots,a_k\}$; in this case $\sigma\tau$ has one more orbit than $\sigma$. The other case is proved in the same manner, (and can even be avoided because the two elements swapped by $\tau$ then belong to the same orbit of $\tau\sigma$).

EDIT : Add parenthesis about the infinite symmetric group

Comment: This perspective is used in a proof of [Zolotarev's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zolotarev%27s_lemma). (I'm not sure what you mean by "a symmetric group on any finite set"—every such group is an isomorphm of $S_n$, so it seems not to be a generalisation.  But I guess you're emphasising that your answer doesn't depend on the order on $\{1,\ldots, n\}$?)

Comment: I think it was also excluded by the OP: 'Using a decomposition into disjoint cycles, one can simply compute what happens when multiplying by a transposition. This is not bad, but here the sign still feels like an ex machina sort of formula.'

Comment: @LSpice : exactly, this shows that the signature does not depend on the choice of a numbering of the elements of the set.

Comment: @SimonWadsley: you're right if it is about proving that the signature is a morphism of groups, but before that, one has to define the signature in one way or another.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417690/conceptual-reason-why-the-sign-of-a-permutation-is-well-defined/454961#comment1177968_454961), of course you're right, but that also just follows from the fact that it is a homomorphism to an Abelian group.

Answer (score 4):

There is an interesting wrong "proof" by Hans Liebeck in the American Mathematical Monthly article [Even and odd permutations](https://doi.org/10.2307/2316678): He claims that if a product of transpositions $(1\;i)$ is the identity, then each transposition $(1\;s)$ appears an even number of times. However, $(1\;2)(1\;3)(1\;2)(1\;3)(1\;2)(1\;3)=e$ contradicts this "fact". (Thanks to my colleague Florian Möller who noticed this type of mistake in a similar "proof" of mine ...)

Answer (score 3):

Here is my favorite conceptual definition of the determinant, which answers point 6 and looks pretty much inevitable.

If $V$ is an $n$-dimensional $k$-vector space and $T$ is an endomorphism of $V$, then $T$ induces an endomorphism of $\Lambda^n V$. Since $\Lambda^n V$ is one-dimensional, this endomorphism must be multiplication by some scalar, which is none other than $\det T$. It is clear that if $T$ is invertible then so is the induced map on $\Lambda^n V$, and that $\det$ is multiplicative, so it defines a homomorphism $GL(V)\to k^\times$.

Once you have the determinant you can just define $\text{sgn}(\pi)$ as the determinant of the permutation matrix corresponding to $\pi$.

Comment: How do you prove that the nth exterior power is one-dimensional?

Comment: Right, now that I think of it, we can hardly say anything about exterior powers without the notion of the sign of a permutation.

Comment: @SamHopkins Here's a workaround. Have $\{e_i\}$ be a basis of $\mathbb R^n$. Then specify a multilinear map $\det: (\mathbb R^n)^n\to\mathbb R$ by $\det(e_1,e_2,\dots e_n)=1$ and $\det(v_1,v_2,\dots v_n)=0$ whenever the vectors $v_1\dots v_n$ are linearly dependent. You then prove this is antisymmetric by setting any pair of arguments to $u+v$. Then define the determinant of any operator by $\det A\equiv\det(Ae_1,Ae_2,\dots Ae_n)$.

Comment: @AlexArvanitakis How do these two properties make the map well-defined?

Comment: The real problem with this method is showing that $\bigwedge^n V$ is nonzero. It is clearly spanned by $e_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge e_n$, but you need some argument to show that this element is not itself zero. Usually the determinant is used for that, which is constructed using a sign. This was discussed extensively in the comments to the original question. That said, there might be a noncommutative Gröbner basis argument that shows the nonvanishing, but this is probably getting too technical.

Comment: @AntoineLabelle: yes, well you do need to write every permutation as some (fixed) product of transpositions, which I suppose is the nontrivial step in this approach. Once you've done that you've constructed (a) $\det$ by specifying its matrix elements.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn the Gröbner basis argument is extremely transparent - Diamond Lemma is not at all technical :)

Answer (score 3):

My first thought was to do it by induction and trace what happens to $n$. So (first draft) assume it's true for $S_{n-1}$, which fixes $n$. Let $\sigma \in S_n$, and let $i = \sigma(n)$. If you could write $\sigma$ as a product of both an odd and an even number of transpositions, you could then write $(i \ n) \cdot \sigma$ as a product of both an even and an odd number of transpositions. But $\sigma$ takes $n$ to $i$ and $(i \ n)$ takes it back to $n$, so $(i \ n) \cdot \sigma$ lies in $S_{n-1}$, and must be a product of even or odd numbers of transpositions but not both.

As the first commenter below pointed out in like a minute :-) this doesn't get at the main issue, which is that you could have $\sigma \in S_n$ that you can write as both an odd product and an even product in some larger ambient $S_n$. It's really about the base case in the induction, which is the identity: if you can prove that this can't happen for the identity, you've really done it for any $\sigma \in S_n$. (If $\sigma$ is a product of both an odd and an even number of transpositions, we get that $\mbox{id} = \sigma \cdot \sigma^{-1}$ is a product of an odd + even = odd number of transpositions.)

If we stick to looking at the identity, it's clear in principle what happens to $n$: it starts as the last element, and ends there too. So we should be able to pull it out! To help picture this, make one more reduction, which is that it's equivalent to look at odd vs. even products of adjacent transpositions. This is because any transposition is conjugate by a series of adjacent transpositions to an adjacent transposition, and conjugation preserves parity.

All that said, suppose we can write the identity as a product of an odd number of adjacent transpositions in some $S_n$. Pick the smallest such $n$, and let the number of adjacent transpositions used be minimal for that $n$. Represent the product as a (singular) braid diagram, with the strings ordered left to right as $1, \ldots , n$, and with each adjacent transposition represented by a singular crossing. String $n$ begins to the right of every other string, and, since our product is the identity, it ends to the right of every other string too. This means, for any other string $i$, that $n$ begins and ends on the same (right) side of $i$, and hence (here's the whole point!) crosses $i$ an even number of times. Now I hope you see the punch line: pull the string! I.e., pulling the $n$-th string all the way to the right, out of the braid, reduces the number of crossings (adjacent transpositions in the product) if there were any, but keeps it even, contradicting the minimality above.

Comment: This needs a little more work to actually be a full proof, I think - just because $(i n) \cdot \sigma$ can't be written as a product of both an even and odd number of transpositions in $S_{n - 1}$ doesn't mean it can't be written as a product of both an even and odd number of transpositions in $S_n$, because there are more transpositions in $S_n$.

Comment: You're right, I should have been careful in my inductive hypothesis that though $\sigma$ fixes everything after $n$, it might be factored in a larger ambient symmetric group. So the real heart of things is the base case, i.e., showing that the identity can't be expanded as a product of an odd number of transpositions. I'd like to find a good inductive argument for that but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Hi Eugene, you should merge your accounts, then you can edit your posts. Ask the moderators about it.

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! Please use the [Contact Us](/contact) form to have your accounts merged, to regain full control over your posts.

Answer (score 2):

[image: The permutahedron as zonotope, Mercator projection]

Think of permutations as acyclic orientations on a complete graph. One reaches neighboring permutations by edge flips that preserve acyclicity; these correspond to adjacent pair swaps. Each edge acts as a toggle switch, so every cycle in the neighbor graph is even, and the parity of a permutation is well-defined.

The illustration is a permutahedron as zonotope (Mercator projection). [Classification of Vertex-Transitive Zonotopes](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-021-00303-6) gives a survey and generalization of this point of view.

Comment: This feels like a "Proof Without Words" that I'm not getting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm building off ideas in the answer of manzana and a comment of Vitali Kapovitch. I hope people won't mind one more answer to this excellent question.

The plan is to show that the orthogonal group is disconnected. Then, $O(n) \to \pi_0 O(n)$ will be a surjective group homomorphism with an interesting kernel. If we also know that $O(n)$ is generated by hyperplane reflections, then by continuously adjusting a general product of hyperplane reflections we obtain a similar product where all the hyperplanes coincide. (This uses connectivity of the space of hyperplanes). So $O(n)$ has at most two path components.

Let us visualize $O(n)$ as a space of orthonormal frames given by column vectors. We consider $O(n-1) \subseteq O(n)$ by setting the final vector of a frame to $e_n$.  Write $Q(n) \subseteq O(n)$ for the open subset of frames where $-e_n$ is not the final vector of the frame. We have $O(n) \subseteq Q(n+1) \subseteq O(n+1)$. That $O(n)$ is disconnected follows from applying the following lemma to a putative path connecting the two elements of $O(1)$.

**Lemma** Let $n \geq 1$. Any path contained in $O(n+1)$ and connecting endpoints in $O(n)$ gives rise to

- another path with the same endpoints but contained in $Q(n+1)$
- another path with the same endpoints but contained in $O(n)$.

**Proof**

The first claim works a bit differently for $n=1$ and $n \geq 2$. When $n$ is large, the open set $U$ is the complement of a submanifold of codimension at least 2, so we can perturb the path to avoid the bad set. (This step requires justification, but at least it's *intuitive*.) If $n=1$, we can adjust the path by multiplying both diagonal entries by the sign of the entry in the lower right.

The second claim follows because frames in $Q(n+1)$ rotate into $O(n)$ without much fuss. Choose coordinates so that $e_{n+1}$ points directly up. Apply the first claim so that, along the whole path of frames, the final vector never points straight down. We are going to operate on the whole path at once, rotating each frame around a different axis. No need to touch the frames where the final vector already points up! For every other frame on the path, we choose our axis to be the orthogonal complement of the 2-plane spanned by the final vector and the vertical. Then, coordinating speeds, we rotate each frame so that, at time $t=1$, all the final vectors point exactly upwards.

Answer (score 0):

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Here's a conceptual explanation for why there exists a determinant homomorphism $\det:\GL_n(\mathbb R)\to \GL_1(\mathbb R)$.

It comes from the action of
$\GL_n(\mathbb R)$ on $L^1(\mathbb R^n)$.

The number $\det(A)$ encodes the way in which the $L^1$-norm of a function changes as it gets pulled back by the linear map $A:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$.

Now, you might (righfully) complain that this actually gives $\lvert\det(A)\rvert$, and not $\det(A)$….
 But you can't complain that it's not conceptual.

Comment: It seems to me this kills the problem. If one has a determinant then one can define the sign as the det of the permutation matrix, but if one takes the absolute value this just gives the homomorphism from $S_n$ to the trivial group $\{1\}$. I guess one would need the change of variable formula without $|\cdot|$ but this means the theory of integration of differential forms.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam. I know. I'm only answering item 6 of the question. Not the question about $\Sigma_n$.

Comment: I see. There is in fact a way of constructing the det without the absolute value first and then the sign function. Maybe I'll add that to my answer later.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a repetition of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4157601/303300) answer, except for few modifications.]

Fix ${ n \in \mathbb{Z} _{\gt 0} }.$

> **Def**: A list ${ [k _1, \ldots, k _n] }$ made by taking ${ 1, \ldots, n }$ in some order is called an arrangement.

> **Def**: For ${ \sigma \in S _n }$ and arrangement ${ [k _1, \ldots, k _n] },$ let ${ \sigma \ast [k _1, \ldots, k _n] := ( [k _1, \ldots, k _n] \text{ after putting whatever is in slot } i \text{ into slot } \sigma(i) ) }.$

We see ${ \sigma \ast [k _1, \ldots, k _n] }$ ${ = [k _{\sigma ^{-1} (1)} , \ldots, k _{\sigma ^{-1} (n)} ] }$

> In ${ [k _1, \ldots, k _n] }$ ${ \rightsquigarrow \sigma \ast [k _1, \ldots, k _n] },$ the ${ k _t }$ which gets sent to slot ${ j }$ satisfies ${ \sigma (t) = j }$ that is ${ t = \sigma ^{-1} (j) }.$

Also ${ \sigma \ast (\pi \ast [k _1, \ldots, k _n]) }$ ${ = (\sigma \pi) \ast [k _1, \ldots, k _n] }$

> In ${ [k _1, \ldots, k _n] }$ ${ \rightsquigarrow \sigma \ast (\pi \ast [k _1, \ldots, k _n]) },$ ${ k _i }$ is first sent to slot ${ \pi (i) }$ and then to slot ${ \sigma (\pi (i)) }.$
> And ${ [k _1, \ldots, k _n] }$ ${ \rightsquigarrow (\sigma \pi) \ast [k _1, \ldots, k _n] }$ has the same effect.

> **Notation**: ${ [k _1, \ldots, k _n] \overset{\sigma}{\rightsquigarrow} [\ell _1, \ldots, \ell _n ] }$ will mean ${ [\ell _1, \ldots, \ell _n] = \sigma \ast [k _1, \ldots, k _n] }.$

---

Every ${ \sigma \in S _n }$ is a product of disjoint cycles. It leads to: Is every cycle further a product of transpositions ?

> **Eg 1**: Consider ${ (1234) }.$
> It is easy to verify ${ (1234) }$ ${ = (34)(24)(14) },$ but here is one way to come up with this in the first place.
> We have ${ [1,2,3,4] \overset{(1234)}{\rightsquigarrow} [4 , 1, 2 , 3] .}$ To get the same effect using transpositions, ${ [1,2,3,4] \overset{(14)}{\rightsquigarrow} [{\color{green}{4}}, 2, 3, 1] }$ ${ \overset{(24)}{\rightsquigarrow} [{\color{green}{4}}, {\color{green}{1}}, 3, 2] }$ ${ \overset{(34)}{\rightsquigarrow} [{\color{green}{4}}, {\color{green}{1}}, {\color{green}{2}}, {\color{green}{3}} ].}$
> So formally ${ (1 2 3 4) \ast [1,2,3,4] }$ ${ = (34) \ast ( (24) \ast ( (14) \ast [1,2,3,4] ) ) , }$ that is ${ (1234) \ast [1,2,3,4] }$ ${ = (34)(24)(14) \ast [1,2,3,4] }$ that is ${ (1234) = (34)(24)(14). }$
> This suggests that in general ${ (a _1 a _2 \ldots a _{k-1}  a _k) }$ ${ = (a _{k-1} a _k) \ldots (a _2 a _k) (a _1 a _k),}$ which is clearly true.

This leads to: Is every transposition further a product of elementary transpositions ?

> **Eg 2**: Consider ${ (14) }.$ We have
>
> [image: elemtransp]
>
> So ${ (14) }$ ${ = (12)(23)(34)(23)(12) }.$ (This is also natural from conjugations).
> Similarly any transposition can be written as a product of an *odd* number of elementary transpositions.

Every ${ \sigma \in S _n }$ is a product of elementary transpositions. This leads to: How are we constrained in writing a ${ \sigma \in S _n }$ as a product of elementary transpositions ?

> Let ${ \sigma \in S _n }.$ We can write it as a product of elementary transpositions ${ \sigma }$ ${ = \tau _1 \ldots \tau _k }.$ Suppose ${ \sigma }$ ${ = \tau ' _1 \ldots \tau ' _{\ell} }$ is another expression as a product of elementary transpositions.
> Now ${ \tau _1 \ldots \tau _k }$ ${ = \tau ' _1 \ldots \tau ' _{\ell} },$ that is ${ \tau ' _{\ell} \ldots \tau ' _1 \tau _1 \ldots \tau _k }$ ${ = \text{id} }.$
> We know ${ [k _1, \ldots, k _n] }$ ${ \rightsquigarrow (j \text{ } j+1) \ast [k _1, \ldots, k _n]  }$ changes the number of inversions by ${ \pm 1 }.$
> So ${ [1, \ldots, n] }$ ${ \rightsquigarrow \tau ' _{\ell} \ast ( \ldots \tau _k \ast [1, \ldots, n] \ldots ) }$ changes number of inversions by ${ \underbrace{\pm 1 \ldots \pm 1} _{k+\ell \text{ terms}} }.$
> But ${ \tau ' _{\ell} \ldots \tau _k \ast [1, \ldots, n] }$ ${ = \text{id} \ast [1, \ldots, n] }$ has ${ 0 }$ inversions.
> So ${ k+\ell }$ must be even, that is ${ k, \ell }$ have the same parity.

So for ${ \sigma \in S _n },$ no matter how we express ${ \sigma }$ as a product of elementary transpositions, the quantity ${ (-1) }$ raised to the number of elementary transpositions remains the same. This invariant is defined as ${ \text{sgn}(\sigma) }.$

Now ${ \text{sgn} : S _n \to \lbrace \pm 1 \rbrace }$ is a homomorphism.

> Let ${ \sigma, \pi  \in S _n }.$ Can write them as products of elementary transpositions, ${ \sigma = \tau _1 \ldots \tau _k }$ and ${ \pi = \tau ' _1 \ldots \tau ' _{\ell} }.$ So ${\text{sgn}( \sigma \pi) }$ ${ = (-1) ^{k+\ell} }$ ${ = (-1) ^k (-1) ^{\ell} }$ ${ = \text{sgn}(\sigma) \text{sgn}(\pi) }.$

From Eg 2, sign of any transposition is ${ (-1) }.$ From Eg 1, sign of any cycle is ${ \text{sgn}(a _1 \ldots a _k) }$ ${ = \text{sgn}(a _{k-1} a _k) \ldots \text{sgn}(a _1 a _k) }$ ${ = (-1) ^{k-1} }.$

---

**Rem**: If only establishing the sign homomorphism were the goal, Eg 1 and Eg 2 are unnecessary. (One can directly see any permutation is a product of elementary transpositions, and proceed with the rest of the argument). But they let us compute signs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider finite complete  oriented graphs with finitely many vertices.  For $G= (X, E)$ , $ G' = (X', E')$, consider a map from $G$ to $G'$ to be a bijection from $X$ to $X'$. Define its sign to be the $\pm 1$, the product of the sign changes between corresponding edges of $G$, and $G'$. It should be clear that the sign of composition of maps is the product of signs of the factors.

Now consider any finite set $X$, and a complete oriented graph $G= (X,E)$. Take a bijection from $X$ to itself, and look at its sign as a map from $(X,E)$ to $(X,E)$. Now change the orienttation of some edges of $G$ and get $G' = (X, E')$.  Look at the sign of the correponding map from $(X,E')$ to $(X,E')$. Can you see that it is the same sign?
Indeed: write $\phi\colon (X,E') \to (X,E')$ as a composition of three maps :
$\mathbb{1}$ from $(X,E')$ to $(X,E)$, $\phi$ from $(X,E)$ to $(X,E)$ and $\mathbb{1}$ from $(X,E)$ to $(X,E')$ ( some abuse of notation occured).

***Added:*** The signature of a bijection between oriented (finite) sets, and not only for bijections from a set to itself, is useful. Take for instance the case of totally ordered finite sets --they get an orientation from the order.  The signature appears when one considers minors of a matrix, and especially [Laplace expansion of a determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion#General_statement).

***Added:*** The answer looks similar to Björn's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/417732).  I consider maps between "oriented sets", that makes it  more "functorial".

Comment: This is similar to Ramras answer, above, I think?

Comment: @Sam Nead:   My signature is a functor :-)

Comment: I don't get the joke.  And I think you have not answered my question.  What is original about your answer?  I suggest you edit to make that clear.

Comment: @Sam Nead:  Thank you for the feedback!  Added more details.

Comment: MathJax note: please use **double stars** `**double stars**`, not $\bf{TeX trickery}$ `$\bf{TeX trickery}$`, for boldface (and `*single stars*` for italics).  I edited accordingly.